# Listview memory leak

Tags: java, android, listview, memory, memory-leaks

I have a simple list view with adapter.
I create 10+ listviewitems dynamically. Then I scroll up and down again and again and again....
I can see that available memory keeps going down...

Where do I need to free and what?
Note - there is an imageview - but in my test I have not used any images so it is View.GONE.

Also - with which tool can I profile the memory usage on the android. I have found yourKit,but how do I configure it for the android (I run the application on the device)/

The Activity class

```
package org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.NewRecipe;


import org.BJ.Food4All.R;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe.Instruction;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook.RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook.SharedData;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.CameraUtil;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.ImageUploadItem;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Instructions extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private final static String mTAG = "Instructions";
    private EditText mInstructionEditText = null;
    private RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter mListViewAdapter = null;
    private Recipe mEditRecipe = PrivateResources.GetRecipe();

    private CameraUtil  mCameraUtil = new CameraUtil(this);

    private int mSelectedEntryIndex = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_recipe_instruction_tab);

        mInstructionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newRecipeInstructionEditTextId);
        View addInstructionButton = findViewById(R.id.naddInstructionButtonId);

        // Sanity check
        if(mInstructionEditText == null || addInstructionButton == null)
        {
            Log.e(mTAG, "NULL pointers");
            // secure exit
            finish();
        }

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        addInstructionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mListViewAdapter = new RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.recipes_instruction_list_single_view_entry, mEditRecipe.GetInstructions());

        setListAdapter(mListViewAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.naddInstructionButtonId:
                AddInstructionToRecipe(v);
                break;

            default:
                Log.e(mTAG, "Invalid ID:" + v.getId());
                // secure exit
                finish();

        }
    }

    private void AddInstructionToRecipe(View v)
    {
        String instructionText = mInstructionEditText.getText().toString();

        if(instructionText == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Instruction newInstruction = new Instruction(   mEditRecipe.GetInstructions().size() + 1,   // Index
                                                        instructionText,                            // The instruction
                                                        null,
                                                        true);

        if( mEditRecipe.AddInstruction(newInstruction) != true)
        {
            // TODO - ERROR
        }
        else
        {
            mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu, android.view.View, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                                    View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.instructions_ctx_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
        menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        mSelectedEntryIndex = menuInfo.position;

        switch(item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.deleteId:
                mEditRecipe.RemoveInstruction(mSelectedEntryIndex);
                mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.takePictureId:
                mCameraUtil.TakePicture();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
                                    int resultCode, 
                                    Intent data) 
    {
//      String imageLocation = mCameraUtil.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = mCameraUtil.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // TODO - switch to parameter passed in the intent!!!! like TakePicture(index);
//      mEditRecipe.GetInstructions().get( mSelectedEntryIndex ).SetBitmap( imageBitmap ); //SetInstructionImageLocation(imageLocation);
        mSelectedEntryIndex = -1;

        // Update the listviewitem with the picture
        mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The adapter class

```
package org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.BJ.Food4All.R;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe.Instruction;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.GlobalDefs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Instruction> 
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Instruction> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Instruction>items) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

        mContext = context;
        mItems  = items;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, 
                        View convertView, 
                        ViewGroup parent) 
    {
          ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

          if (convertView == null) 
          {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_instruction_list_single_view_entry, null);
          }

          if(super.getItem(position) != null)
          {
              holder.instructionIndex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructionNumberTextBoxId);
              holder.instructionText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructionTextTextBoxId);
              holder.instructionImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructionImageViewId);

              Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Eras_Bold.ttf");
              holder.instructionIndex.setTypeface(tf);
              holder.instructionIndex.setTextSize(30);
              holder.instructionIndex.setTextColor(GlobalDefs.GetHeadlineColor());
              holder.instructionIndex.setText( Integer.toString(mItems.get(position).getIndex()));

              tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Arial.ttf");
              holder.instructionText.setTypeface(tf);
              holder.instructionText.setTextSize(14);
              holder.instructionText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
              holder.instructionText.setText(mItems.get(position).getText());

              Bitmap imageBitmap = mItems.get(position).GetBitmap();
//              String imageLocation = mItems.get(position).GetInstructionImageLocation();
              if(imageBitmap != null)
              {
                  holder.instructionImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);// setImageURI( Uri.parse(imageLocation ));
                  holder.instructionImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
              else
              {
                  holder.instructionImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }

              convertView.setTag(holder);
              convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          } 
          else 
          {
          }

          return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    static class ViewHolder 
    {
          TextView  instructionIndex;
          TextView  instructionText;
          ImageView instructionImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is correct to classify this as a bug, but every time you use Typeface.createFromAsset if creates a new font asset and does not release it. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904).

What you can do is load the typefaces when you load your app and reference them statically. I put my typefaces in Application.

```
public class YourApp extends android.app.Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // typeface caching
        initializeTypefaces();
    }

    public static class Fonts {
        public static Typeface THEOREM;
    }

    private void initializeTypefaces(){
        Fonts.THEOREM   = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/theorem.otf");
    }
}
```

And then I do this in my adapter:

```
textView.setTypeface(YourApp.Fonts.THEOREM);
```

You can go [here](http://trace.adityalesmana.com/2010/08/declare-global-variable-in-android-via-android-app-application/) to see how to use Application in Android.

Lastly, it looks like your still creating your ViewHolder every time instead of only when convertView is null. I would review this video to get the whole picture.  http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Here is an example of how I use the ViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.text1  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text1);
        holder.text2  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text2);
        holder.text1.setTypeface(YourApp.Fonts.THEOREM); // only happens once when recycling!

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText("someText");
    holder.text2.setText("someText");
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Really good help - with the viedos as well. Did not knows it exists... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I have another question, if my adapter inflate a different layout according to the position - first and last have special layout (rounded edge backgournd picture). I currently use in the getView function the following getItem(position) and inflate different layout according it. How do I do it without inflate everytime???

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I would do your best to inflate the same layout and just make changes to the background image to get your rounded corner effect. If this is only header and footer, you can take a look at the addHeader and addFooter functions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View, java.lang.Object, boolean)

Comment: Pointed out a bug (should be fixed in Android 4.0 now) and mentioned the concepts of convertView. This post definitely earns a few upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to free the resources `if convertView != null`. if it is you could find your `Views and null` them. You could also try to get the **Bitmap of your ImageView and recycle** it.
you could also  add your **ViewHolder** as a member to your `RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter` and instantiate it once in constructor.

Comment: Regarding the Bitmap issue - If I have X listviewitems, and only N out of X are shown on the screen - are the other being recycled automaticly with its bitmaps? Usually when application has a listview with images and querying for more results from the server, all the already D/L data is kept and not being recycled. Any ideas regarding this

Comment: I'm not shure if I get your problem right: If you show only N of X items I assume that you didn't save Bitmaps in the mass of M in X which are not in N. So there are no resources to clear in M. Recycling  does not happen automatically. ListView gives you the convertView as a parameter instead, if this item was shown. If convertView != null it holds the View from the last Item that was scrolled out of the range of the Screen. After you call findViewById to fill your holder, you can try to call ´((BitmapDrawable)holder.instructionImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle()`