#   ViewPager: SetText of inflated view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, settext

I'm trying to set the text of a TextView in a layout using ViewPager.  This is the code I have:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Panel);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    String text;

    if (Math.floor(hours) <= 12)
        text= hourFormat.format((Math.floor(hours)));

    else
        text= hourFormat.format((Math.floor(hours) - 12));


    Typeface FontType = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/TIMES_SQ_0.TTF");

    View sResource = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.setup, null);
    Method = (TextView) sResource.findViewById(R.id.Method);
    Method.setTypeface(FontType);
    Method.setTextSize(20);
    Method.setText(text);
```

The ViewPager works fine, setting the font and size don't work.  Setting the text does not work either.  I don't know why setText doesn't work.  Also, that text is dynamic so I can't use a resource string to set it.

To clarify: hours is the hour of the day.

Comment: Just a note - setting font like that you'll have a memory leak in pre-ICS devices - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057010/listview-memory-leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this piece of code you initialize `text` but never assign any value to it.

```
String text;

...

Method.setText(text);
```

Do something like:

```
String text;

...

text = "my text";    

Method.setText(text);
```

Or if you assign it elsewhere, just remove `String text;`

Comment: I just don't show it, but text is changed dynamically.  I meant to show that i'm setting the text with a variable.

Comment: Then please show it, because it's where the real problem lies. And if you do have this line: `String text;` in your code then even if you really change it dynamically it gets reset by this line.

Comment: I don't really get your code. It looks like it's an `Activity` or `Fragment`, because you set an adapter for `ViewPager` in it. If it's true, than your `Method` `TextView` (btw, don't start variable names with capital letter) is inside your `Activity`, not `ViewPager` (otherwise you'd initialize it inside the adapter). So the `ViewPager` has nothing to do with the question, has it? Try removing the lines which set Typeface and textSize, just to see if the text changes. Also `Log.d("MyActivity", text);` to see if the value exists, maybe it's empty? I have to get some sleep now, see you later

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was that I should have set the text in ViewPager where the view is being inflated anyways.  Sorry for the confusion in my question, I'll be sure to be clearer next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value, you have to give your `String text` a value. Something like this:

```
String text = "This is the text I want in my view";
```

Once you add that, it should work.