# Autoscrollable title in Android Actionbar (Marquee)

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar, android-scroll

is there a possibility to make the title of an Android ActionBar scroll automatically (marquee) if it's too large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try implementing my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title/8748802#8748802) and add `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to the TextView...? Worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Well I have done this way:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    try {
        Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        TextView toolbarTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);
        toolbarTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        toolbarTextView.setFocusable(true);
        toolbarTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        toolbarTextView.requestFocus();
        toolbarTextView.setSingleLine(true);
        toolbarTextView.setSelected(true);
        toolbarTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

        // set text on Textview

        toolbarTextView.setText("Hello Android ! This is a sample marquee text. That's great. Enjoy");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
```

Hope this will help you.