# Set scrolling for application name

Tags: android, android-manifest

My application name has 15 characters. But in apps list of android device does not shows the full name. So I want to set `marquee` for my `lable` in android `manifest`. But I dont know how even I didn't know wheather it is possible or not.

I was googling it near 4 hours but the solution is only for title of each activity and not for application name.

sample image for reference:

[image]

This is sample image taken from google. I could not take screenshot of my device. 
Note the red marked name. I want this name to be scroll. If it is possible means please help me friends.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to make the name scroll on the user's device, as this is (probably) a launcher feature. Unless the user's launcher is able to scroll long app names, it's not going to scroll. This is not something you can control through your app.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that pro grammatically. Thats an default functionality of the every single OS manufactures . Its depend upon them only. Some manufactures will set marque and some of then wont set.

Answer (score 0):

**Marquee is not supported on all android mobile devices**. Anyways check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034639/autoscrollable-title-in-android-actionbar-marquee) you may be lucky ;)