# position the Application name to the center of the sceen for an android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to know how i can position the Application Name to the center , by default the position is to the left of the screen.

I did refer few tips on alignment but seems to be not working.
the position is for the application name and not for individual activity name.
Also the need to set a combination of colors to the text of application name which currently i am using the setcolor method .

Comment: You really mean the center of the screen?

Comment: yea i mean at the top where the application name is displayed its by default displayed at the left .. i need it in the center

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261835/826657 you may see this !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it  (for the app or activity name in the default bar on the top)

```
((TextView)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Title" />
    </LinearLayout>
```