# Customize theme in actionbar-sherlock does not work

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I know that there are varios questions about customized theme for actionbar-sherlock. I also try the accepted answer but no thing change. Here is my theme:

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And here is my activity declaration:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.Home"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" />
```

My applciation will run on android 2.1+, so I declare the android version as:

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I want to set new background to the actionbar sherlock as well as new text font for the title but I can't. Please tell me where is my mistakes to make this works.

UPDATE: Java source
I user overlay actionbar style:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

Here is the code to add menu items:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
            .setActionView(R.layout.search_edittext)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("Theme");
    sub.add(0, R.style.Theme_Sherlock, 0, "Default");
    sub.add(0, R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light, 0, "Light");
    sub.add(0, R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar, 0, "Light (Dark Action Bar)");
    sub.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
};
```

Thanks .

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the code result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in `oncreate()` method in your activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background));
```

It will solve this.

Comment: Does this code just set background to actionbar? How to set text typeface or color?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title