# Custom font for ActionBarSherlock tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to set font for the "Video" and "Image" tabs in `ActionBarSherlock`. I have used the following code to do so. Its showing accurately in ICS but not in the lower version device but I have shown accurate output in the other part of this application by setting TYPE FACE like ...

```
a.settypeface("ab.tttf");
a.settext("VIDEO");
```

But how to do I set a `TypeFace` in the `ActionBar` in this code:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("IMAGE"), AFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("VIDEO"), BFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: Hello really like to know about your solution. Whether you get solution or not ?

Answer (score 9):

Okay . I found it myself some where on SO.

First make an xml file with this in it: tab_title.xml

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/action_custom_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Custom title"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

Then in the class where you in instantiate your ActionBar use this code to set the text on each of the tabs. (This example is using ActionBarSherlock.)

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

String[] tabNames = {"Tab 1","Tab 2","Tab 3"};

for(int i = 0; i<bar.getTabCount(); i++){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);

    TextView titleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.action_custom_title);
    titleTV.setText(tabNames[i]);
    //Here you can also add any other styling you want.

    bar.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you could create a Special Actionbar class. 
Simply create a Class `myBar extends Sherlockactionbar` and put in the settypeface. If you now create that Bar in your view it will have the Typeface as you whish. For example here is an button with a new Typeface.

```
public class ChangedButton extends Button{

    public ChangedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/viking2.TTF");
        this.setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

regards

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String s = "VIDEO";
SpannableString mSS = new SpannableString(s);
mSS.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s.length(), 0);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(mSS),
                BFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: @Archie.bgpc but i want to add Roboto font to navigation tab in action bar sherlock.....any suggestions

Comment: You can set a custom typeface in SpannableString object too. Check out this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title) post

Answer (score 2):

First create following custom `TypefaceSpan` class in your project.Bit changed version of [Custom TypefaceSpan](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8) to enable to use both `.otf` and `.ttf` fonts.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan{

    /*Cache to save loaded fonts*/
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> typeFaceCache= new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);
    private Typeface mTypeface;
    public TypefaceSpan(Context context,String typeFaceName)
    {
        StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(typeFaceName,".");
        String fontName=tokens.nextToken();
        mTypeface=typeFaceCache.get(fontName);

        if(mTypeface==null)
        {
            mTypeface=Constants.getFont(context, typeFaceName);
            //cache the loaded font
            typeFaceCache.put(fontName, mTypeface);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

}
```

Now apply code like this:(I used this on one of my Bangla apps successfully)

```
        SpannableString mstKnwTitle=new SpannableString(getString(R.string.e_mustknow_tab));
        SpannableString cntctsTitle=new SpannableString(getString(R.string.e_number_tab));


        TypefaceSpan span=new TypefaceSpan(this, "solaimanlipi.ttf");

        mstKnwTitle.setSpan(span, 0, mstKnwTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);     
        cntctsTitle.setSpan(span, 0, mstKnwTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        Tab tab= actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText(mstKnwTitle);
        tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);


        tab= actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText(cntctsTitle);
        tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Original inspiration of my answer was:[Styling the Android Action Bar title using a custom typeface](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not getting any guidance. I am not sure with my answer's result but yes you can defiantly get idea to make it as you want.

Let me try to help you. I think you have to somewhat play with the in-built default resources of the android sdk.

You have to create custom style:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
</style>

 <style name="Widget.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">HERE YOU CAN GIVE YOUR FONT</item>
</style>
```

You can also refer [this SO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3afontFamily).

Now just apply that theme to your activity and you will get Font of the TabText as you want.

Comment me if have any query.

Enjoy coding... :)

**In EXTRA**

Another solution could be to modify the tab image to include the text, with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or photoshop something, and then just set those images in the tabs, instead of images and text. It is a bit of an awkward way of doing it but it would work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not a good solution. What if the tab text is generated programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this:

```
// Set a custom font on all of our ActionBar Tabs
private boolean setCustomFontToActionBarTab(Object root) {

    // Found the container, that holds the Tabs. This is the ScrollContainerView to be specific,
    // but checking against that class is not possible, since it's part of the hidden API.
    // We will check, if root is an instance of HorizontalScrollView instead,
    // since ScrollContainerView extends HorizontalScrollView.
    if (root instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {
        // The Tabs are all wraped in a LinearLayout
        root = ((ViewGroup) root).getChildAt(0);
        if (root instanceof LinearLayout) {
            // Found the Tabs. Now we can set a custom Font to all of them.
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) root).getChildCount(); i++) {
                LinearLayout child = ((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) root).getChildAt(i));
                TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) child.getChildAt(0);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/font.ttf");
                actionBarTitle.setTypeface(tf)
            }
            return true;
        }

    } 
    // Search ActionBar and the Tabs. Exclude the content of the app from this search.
    else if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) root;
        if (group.getId() != android.R.id.content) {
            // Found a container that isn't the container holding our screen layout.
            // The Tabs have to be in here.
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (setCustomFontToActionBarTab(group.getChildAt(i))) {
                    // Found and done searching the View tree
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Found nothing
    return false;
}
```

Call it with this:

```
ViewParent root = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();
setCustomFontToActionBarTab(root);
```