# android custom font for tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I would like to have a custom font for my tabs. Here's what I have tried:

```
<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" 
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:typeface">@assets/fonts/heartbre</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

But I got an error in `<item name="android:typeface">@assets/fonts/heartbre</item>`.

Has anybody here tried customizing the font of tabs?

Comment: i think there is no way to use custom font from xml file . u will need to use `Typeface.createFromAsset` to use ur own font for application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only (currently) available way to set Fonts is to **do it programatically**:

```
TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/heartbre.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

However, I hope there will be a xml-way to do it some day!

Answer (score 0):

You can only define custom fonts by code or through styleable attributes in a custom object extending `TexView` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)

Answer (score 0):

No possibility to add manually from XML (as far as I know!). You have to do it within your code:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/heartbre.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question [setting custom font for sherlock action bar tab android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436364/setting-custom-font-for-sherlock-action-bar-tab-android/16566277) and check my answer. So far the solution I posted there is the best working one in all cases.
Hope it will help.