# Sherlock Actionbar Custom Font

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, custom-font

I want to change the font of the **Action Bar Title**, **Tabs** and **Menu Items** to Roboto.

I am trying to figure out if this can be done via Styles ? since i am not able to create a custom view for these which is the best way to assign the custm font.

I have gone through the following links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681975/155196

[How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code that did it for me:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809944/default-font-set-on-android) for what fonts are available by default on android.
From what I read adding other fonts is not possible without sub-classing your views, so I can't help you there.

EDIT: I may be wrong. Check this out: http://www.jayway.com/2013/01/22/custom-typeface-in-android/
and here: http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/

Comment: +1 how about roboto?can you have roboto set with this solution?