# Is there a way to set font style for the entire app

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar

I'm trying to apply a custom font style for my app..I know:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

But I want to apply custom font style for the entire app including the action bar tabs and all the text view.

is there a "supper" way to apply a custom font for the whole app??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a custom font for the whole application in a single point yet, but you have to set the typeface for every view by yourself.

See this answer: [Android: Want to set custom fonts for whole application not runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4395391/1926391)

**Custom ActionBar Styling**

[ActionBar Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681975/1926391)

[ActionBar Title](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I saw your link before I put my question.
Ok ...How do I set the action bar tabs font?

Comment: You have to add a custom text view to the tabs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14681975/1926391

Comment: sorry I'm not using Sherlock actionbar

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set an entire applications typeface, but if you are looking for a more general programatic solution, I created a static class that can be used to set the Typeface of an entire view (Activity UI). Note that I am working with Mono (C#) but you can implement it easily using Java.

You can pass this class a layout or a specific view that you want to customize. If you want to be super efficient you could implement it using the Singleton pattern.

```
public static class AndroidTypefaceUtility 
{
    static AndroidTypefaceUtility()
    {
    }
    //Refer to the code block beneath this one, to see how to create a typeface.
    public static void SetTypefaceOfView(View view, Typeface customTypeface)
    {
    if (customTypeface != null && view != null)
    {
            try
            {
                if (view is TextView)
                    (view as TextView).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is Button)
                    (view as Button).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is EditText)
                    (view as EditText).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is ViewGroup)
                    SetTypefaceOfViewGroup((view as ViewGroup), customTypeface);
                else
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: {0} is type of {1} and does not have a typeface property", view.Id, typeof(View));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility threw:\n{0}\n{1}", ex.GetType(), ex.StackTrace);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: customTypeface / view parameter should not be null");
            }
        }

        public static void SetTypefaceOfViewGroup(ViewGroup layout, Typeface customTypeface)
        {
            if (customTypeface != null && layout != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < layout.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    SetTypefaceOfView(layout.GetChildAt(i), customTypeface);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: customTypeface / layout parameter should not be null");
            }
        }

    }
```

In your activity you will need to create a Typeface object. I create mine in the OnCreate() using a .ttf file placed in my Resources/Assets/ directory. Make sure that the file is marked as an Android Asset in its' properties.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{               
    ...
    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.signInView_LinearLayout);
    Typeface allerTypeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(base.Assets,"Aller_Rg.ttf");
    AndroidTypefaceUtility.SetTypefaceOfViewGroup(rootLayout, allerTypeface);
}
```