# how to add Custom Fonts in ActionBar?

Tags: android

I am using Sherlock Action bar I want to use Custom Fonts on the Action bar in three places

1. Title
2. Tabs
3. Menu Items.

If someone has used custom Fonts, please do share on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please look yourself first by googling or searching on stackoverflow:

[How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title#answer-8748802)

It has all details so its easy to implement but please dont ask when its not needed, most of all questions are already asked.