# Changing the font of the application title in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, titlebar

I have a typeface, I want to change the font of the action-bar title in android.
Is there a way to set title typeface like that?

```
this.setTitle(myTitle.toUpperCase()); 
this.setTypefaceofTitle(tf);
```

this is not a copy question, those methods on this link ([How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)) are not working. 
When I try them, eclipse gives that error : **java.lang.noSuchMethodError**

Comment: Do you mean to change the title on the app in `ActionBar`?

Comment: yes, I am editing the question.

Answer (score 15):

Try this,

```
    int actionBarTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView actionBarTitleView = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(actionBarTitle);
Typeface robotoBoldCondensedItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf");
if(actionBarTitleView != null){
    actionBarTitleView.setTypeface(robotoBoldCondensedItalic);
}
```

If it's toolbar means try like as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_color”
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/title_txt” />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then just add any style via programmatically using below comment.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

OR

Change using style. Need one info [click here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Comment: Good solution.  Once you have the TextView you can style it any way you like.

Comment: worked perfect and so simple.  Hope it's future proofed?

Comment: Neat solution, now you have complete control over the text and how it appears.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947849/5713289) from headsvk that helped me. Doing some adjustments I only needed to do this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
TextView myTitle = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(0);
myTitle.setTypeface(font);
```

Doing some tests on my app I found that the title TextView was the first child of the toolbar, so now that I have it I can set changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748802/1943671 you can do like in this answer.

After setting your custom view to the Action Bar like in the link, just give the TextView the typeface:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/yourfont.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTitle);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: how can I find the id of my action-bar title? Obviously, it is not customTitle.

Comment: and those answers in that page: "http://stackoverflow.com/a/8748802/1943671 " does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a custom view and inflating that custom view in the `ActionBar.`
This custom view will contain a `TextView` that you'll get a reference to, and then be able to set a typeface.

See an example here: [How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

Comment: I've already tried it before posting my question. Those solutions on that page are not working :(

Comment: Better is to post your code. Perhaps someone could figure out why it is not working.

Comment: But, my codes are not related with that topic. All I want to do is that,
`setTitleTypeface(myTypeface);`

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported.But you can create custom view for your action bar. [How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/architectsdaughter.ttf");


    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.xml_master_footer, null);


    this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);

    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTypeface(tf);


    //assign the view to the actionbar

    return true;
}
```

and in your menifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: those methods on this link (How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?) are not working. When I try them, eclipse gives that error : java.lang.noSuchMethodError

Comment: It requires minimum API version 11. Please check yours