# Android toolbar center title and custom font

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to figure out the right way to use a custom font for the toolbar title, and center it in the toolbar (client requirement).

At the moment, i'm using the good old ActionBar, and I was setting the title to empty value, and using `setCustomView` to put my custom font TextView and center it using ActionBar.LayoutParams.

Is there a better way to do that? Using the new Toolbar as my ActionBar.

Comment: MaterialToolbar supports centering toolbar and it supports changing font too, see: https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#theming-the-top-app-bar

Answer (score 795, accepted):

To use a custom title in your `Toolbar` all you need to do is remember is that `Toolbar` is just a fancy ViewGroup so you can add a custom title like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the `TextView` however you would like because it's just a regular `TextView`. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Comment: suggest use android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" instead.

Comment: Sometimes android:layout_gravity="top" works better for me to align a title TextView with Toolbar's <- arrow.

Comment: This method did not work for me. The title is already set to be the app name.

Comment: You can clear the title text either programmatically with toolbarTop.setTitle(null) or you can remove the label from your manifest

Comment: This also didn't work for me..it appears the name of the app and I have removed the label of the activity in manifest

Comment: If anyone else can't remove the default app name title, do this:
1. Call setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar)
2. Call getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: To keep using default styles for the customised TextView, try something like  `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"` ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455595/getting-actionbar-title-textview-with-appcompat-v7-r21/28034372#28034372)).

Comment: you answer is so great, BUT, android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding" never center text, because point of center of row, It is displaced.

Comment: Using textview inside toolbar causing problem with search widget in toolbar. If i use search widget in toolbar, on click of search icon it increase height of toolbar to nearby half of screen height but as i remove that textview from toolbar it start working properly. Any idea?

Comment: @MrEngineer13 I'm not able to apply this for CollapsingToobarLayout. Any suggestions???

Comment: None of this worked for me. Possibly because my toolbar includes a menu, which causes Android to ditch the TextView layout for the title.

Comment: You may also remove the default app name title by using an empty `android:label` in the AndroidManifest declaration.

Comment: adding android:paddingRight="?attr/actionBarSize" can help to center the text in the middle of your screen in the case you have a button (home, navigation drawer, etc)

Comment: Downvoted this a year ago, because using styles is cleaner. But if you need a custom font, this is the best way. Just did the same thing. Though, you'll need a bit more configuration to make sure your activity title is set on the correct view.

Comment: What will be happened when there is Hamburger icon on Toolbar? It will be not in center of complete toolbar width, it will be in center of **ToolbarWidth - HamburgerIconWidth**.

Comment: Only way to get a custom font as far as I was able to try.

Comment: This answer is not a good idea because you can't use it in a `scrolling activity` when you scroll down the custom `Textview` will hide and original title is shown!  you can test it ! is answer is very confusing .

Comment: for me, layout_gravity doesn't work in toolbar. it doesn't show up in auto-complete, and when I manually type it in, it does nothing.

Comment: @Akshay try to move `TextView` into a `FrameLayout` wrap in toolbar

Comment: I had to use ```androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar``` to be able to put a Textview inside the toolbar

Comment: I get a warning when going with this approach ```requestLayout() improperly called by com.google.android.material.textview...during layout: running second layout pass```

Answer (score 86):

This's just to help to join all pieces using [@MrEngineer13 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/4848308) with @Jonik and  @Rick Sanchez comments with the right order to help to achieve title centered easly!!

The layout with `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title` :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The way to achieve with the right order:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Please don't forget to upvote [@MrEngineer13 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/4848308) !!!

Here is a sample project [ToolbarCenterTitleSample](https://github.com/g2obregon/ToolbarCenterTitleSample)

[image]

Hope to help somebody else ;)

Comment: if I set  setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); to enalbe back arrow. Then title is not coming center. I have tried like setting actionBar.setTitle(""); and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false). But still not able to solve the issue

Comment: Are you tested it for a `Scrolling Activity` ?

Comment: it's true that with the back arrow, the title is not centered (it's off to the right by half the width of the back arrow). I suppose if I were really determined I'd programmatically add enough margin to the right of the textbox as necessary in order to center the text.

Answer (score 71):

The ToolBar title is stylable. Any customization you make has to be made in the theme. I'll give you an example.

**Toolbar layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle.Event"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />
```

**Styles:**

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ToolBarStyle.Base"/>

<style name="ToolBarStyle.Base" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle.Event" parent="ToolBarStyle">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!--Any text styling can be done here-->
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/event_title_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is the correct way. Adding another `TextView` is a bit hacky, but the reflection answer is just plain evil.

Comment: Clean, but you can't set a custom font from style. Sadly.

Comment: Neither can you change the alignment of the title.

Comment: @Terry I suppose that's because google wants you to stick to the design guidelines. Personally, I hate it when some app tries to make the ToolBar/ActionBar fancy.

Comment: @user1560102 there's nothing hacky about adding a TextView to the Toolbar. That's what it was designed for.

Comment: This does not center the text.

Comment: @niqueco: you can change the font using `<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_font_here</item>`

Comment: I followed your style code, the font has worked but I did not find a way to align text to the center. I tried this: <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

Comment: could not center the text, using styles.xml . I don't think it is possible to change the text alignment using styles.

Answer (score 54):

we don't have direct access to the ToolBar title TextView so we use reflection to access it.

```
  private TextView getActionBarTextView() {
    TextView titleTextView = null;

    try {
        Field f = mToolBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        titleTextView = (TextView) f.get(mToolBar);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return titleTextView;
}
```

Comment: Is this only when using a custom toolbar instead of the provided one? Otherwise how do you get access to the `Toolbar` object (`mToolbar` here)?

Comment: This is shame, that in the material design guides the title has padding, but it doesn't by default and we even don't have access to the mTitleView. Thank for your answer.

Comment: Worked nicely for the Title. But when tried to obtain the mSubtitleTextView like this, it resulted in an exception.      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Comment: for the subtitle you should use "mSubtitleText", not "mSubtitleTextView"

Comment: if you want use a getActionBarTextView().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) this method or into method textview , java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setGravity(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Note: You can only access the "mTitleTextView" field, after you set the toolbar title! The field is lazy initialized by its first use.

Comment: What if you obfuscate your code with ProGuard and `mTitleTextView` becomes `abcde12345`?

Comment: @voghDev getDeclaredField will throw NoSuchFieldException in that case, resulting in the code not working.

Comment: @voghDev place mTitleTextView in strings.xml and use it in code.

Answer (score 36):

`MaterialToolbar` from [Material Components 1.4.0-alpha02](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.4.0-alpha02) now has the ability to center the toolbar's title by setting the `titleCentered` attribute to `true`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleCentered="true" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Got error attribute titleCentered not found

Comment: Seems to be no longer available (at least in Material Components 1.8.0). *EDIT:*Ensure you are using `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` and NOT `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: @Viks use `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`

Answer (score 35):

Define the following class:

```
public class CenteredToolbar extends Toolbar {

    private TextView centeredTitleTextView;

    public CenteredToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(@StringRes int resId) {
        String s = getResources().getString(resId);
        setTitle(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        getCenteredTitleTextView().setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        return getCenteredTitleTextView().getText().toString();
    }

    public void setTypeface(Typeface font) {
        getCenteredTitleTextView().setTypeface(font);
    }

    private TextView getCenteredTitleTextView() {
        if (centeredTitleTextView == null) {
            centeredTitleTextView = new TextView(getContext());
            centeredTitleTextView.setTypeface(...);
            centeredTitleTextView.setSingleLine();
            centeredTitleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            centeredTitleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            centeredTitleTextView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Title);

            Toolbar.LayoutParams lp = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            centeredTitleTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);

            addView(centeredTitleTextView);
        }
        return centeredTitleTextView;
    }
}
```

...and then just use it instead of regular `Toolbar` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <your.packagename.here.CenteredToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:title="@string/reset_password_page_title"/>

        <!-- Other views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

You still need these 2 lines of code in your `Activity` (as with standard `Toolbar`):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewByid(R.id.toolbar); // note that your activity doesn't need to know that it is actually a custom Toolbar
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
```

That's it! You don't need to hide the standard left-aligned title, don't need to duplicate the same XML code over and over, etc., just use `CenteredToolbar` like if it was default `Toolbar`. You can also set your custom font programatically since you now have direct access to the `TextView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this is quite old but... how can I change text color? I've tried in XML with app:titleTextColor and in code with centeredTitleTextView.setColor. Any ideas, @fraggjkee?

Comment: `centeredTitleTextView.setTextColor(...)` should work

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`?

Answer (score 30):

Here is title text dependant approach to find `TextView` instance from `Toolbar`.

```
  public static TextView getToolbarTitleView(ActionBarActivity activity, Toolbar toolbar){
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    CharSequence actionbarTitle = null;
    if(actionBar != null)
        actionbarTitle = actionBar.getTitle();
    actionbarTitle = TextUtils.isEmpty(actionbarTitle) ? toolbar.getTitle() : actionbarTitle;
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(actionbarTitle)) return null;
    // can't find if title not set
    for(int i= 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(v != null && v instanceof TextView){
            TextView t = (TextView) v;
            CharSequence title = t.getText();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && actionbarTitle.equals(title) && t.getId() == View.NO_ID){
                //Toolbar does not assign id to views with layout params SYSTEM, hence getId() == View.NO_ID
                //in same manner subtitle TextView can be obtained.
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I use this solution:

```
static void centerToolbarTitle(@NonNull final Toolbar toolbar) {
    final CharSequence title = toolbar.getTitle();
    final ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<>(1);
    toolbar.findViewsWithText(outViews, title, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
    if (!outViews.isEmpty()) {
        final TextView titleView = (TextView) outViews.get(0);
        titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        final Toolbar.LayoutParams layoutParams = (Toolbar.LayoutParams) titleView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        toolbar.requestLayout();
        //also you can use titleView for changing font: titleView.setTypeface(Typeface);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works very well, but for some reason it doesn't center properly with toolbars that don't have an item button.

Comment: An addition: if you have a navdrawer or back icon on toolbar, title not stay exactly center. I add an empty setting menu icon for this situation. My empty menu item is: <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@android:color/transparent"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />

Answer (score 17):

No one has mentioned this, but there are some attributes for `Toolbar`:

`app:titleTextColor` for setting the title text color

`app:titleTextAppearance` for setting the title text appearance

`app:titleMargin` for setting the margin

And there are other specific-side margins such as `marginStart`, etc.

Comment: Perfect Solution.. if you are aware of [FontOverride](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-of-application),


just create style in styles.xml

`<style name="customFontTextAppearanceStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>`


and apply it in toolbar


`app:titleTextAppearance="@styles/customFontTextAppearanceStyle"`

Comment: I used this method but nothing happened to my toolbar ! i created a new '<style>' and set it to `app:titleTextAppearanc="style name"`  on the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` TAG

Comment: what about the centering thing?

Answer (score 10):

Without toolbar TextView we can customize font by using below code

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
or
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

public void updateActionbar(String title){
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(title);
    spannableString.setSpan(new TypefaceSpanString(this,  "futurastdmedium.ttf"),
            0, spannableString.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mToolbar.setTitle(spannableString);
}
```

Comment: If you just need to change font, this seems like the most clean solution. NOTE: TypefaceSpanString is just this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17961854

Answer (score 8):

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        customizeToolbar(toolbar);
    }

    public void customizeToolbar(Toolbar toolbar){
        // Save current title and subtitle
        final CharSequence originalTitle = toolbar.getTitle();
        final CharSequence originalSubtitle = toolbar.getSubtitle();

        // Temporarily modify title and subtitle to help detecting each
        toolbar.setTitle("title");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("subtitle");

        for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

            if(view instanceof TextView){
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;


                if(textView.getText().equals("title")){
                    // Customize title's TextView
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams params = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

                    // Apply custom font using the Calligraphy library
                    Typeface typeface = TypefaceUtils.load(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont-1.otf");
                    textView.setTypeface(typeface);

                } else if(textView.getText().equals("subtitle")){
                    // Customize subtitle's TextView
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams params = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

                    // Apply custom font using the Calligraphy library
                    Typeface typeface = TypefaceUtils.load(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont-2.otf");
                    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
                }
            }
        }

        // Restore title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(originalTitle);
        toolbar.setSubtitle(originalSubtitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: solution works great when you put out last two lines of code, it shouldn't be inside the for loop: // Restore title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(originalTitle);
        toolbar.setSubtitle(originalSubtitle);

Answer (score 8):

With the Material Components, starting from the version **`1.4.x`** as [described in the doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md#center-aligned-top-app-bar-example) you can use  the `MaterialToolbar`.

Just add the attribute **`app:titleCentered`** and/or **`app:subtitleCentered`** attributes to `true` on your `MaterialToolbar`.

Something like:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        ... />
```

[image]

With **Compose** using the **Material3** package you can simply use the [**`CenterAlignedTopAppBar`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Vbw.png):

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = { Text("Centered TopAppBar") },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                contentDescription = "Localized description"
            )
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

If you are using Compose and the Material2 package, there isn't a builtin component but you can customize the layout of content inside the `TopAppBar` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67499847/2016562).

Answer (score 6):

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Code:

```
    Toolbar mToolbar = parent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    TextView mToolbarCustomTitle = parent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    //setup width of custom title to match in parent toolbar
    mToolbar.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            int maxWidth = mToolbar.getWidth();
            int titleWidth = mToolbarCustomTitle.getWidth();
            int iconWidth = maxWidth - titleWidth;

            if (iconWidth > 0)
            {
                //icons (drawer, menu) are on left and right side
                int width = maxWidth - iconWidth * 2;
                mToolbarCustomTitle.setMinimumWidth(width);
                mToolbarCustomTitle.getLayoutParams().width = width;
            }
        }
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

A very **quick** and **easy** way to set a custom font is to use a custom `titleTextAppearance` with a `fontFamily`:

Add to *styles.xml*:

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF202230</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/varela_round_regular</item>
</style>
```

In your **res** folder create a **font** folder (Ex: *varela_round_regular.ttf*)

Read the official guide to find out more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 6):

Use `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` and `app:titleCentered="true"` tag

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleCentered="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution that I used for this problem:

```
 public static void applyFontForToolbarTitle(Activity a){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) a.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if(view instanceof TextView){
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if(tv.getText().equals(a.getTitle())){
                    tv.setTypeface(getRuneTypefaceBold(a));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For center gravity I think it would be necessary to change layout params to match_parent horizontally and then:

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

Now using Material Design 3 we can align the title in the center without doing extra work or without adding a text view in the toolbar

Added below dependencies in `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

To align the title in the center We need to use the below properly

```
 app:titleCentered="true"
```

To align subtitles in the center we need to use the below property

```
app:subtitleCentered="true"
```

Sample Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="AskNilesh"
        app:subtitle="Nilesh"
        app:subtitleCentered="true"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if anything changed in the appcompat library but it's fairly trivial, no need for reflection.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// loop through all toolbar children right after setting support 
// action bar because the text view has no id assigned

// also make sure that the activity has some title here
// because calling setText() with an empty string actually
// removes the text view from the toolbar

TextView toolbarTitle = null;
for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

    // assuming that the title is the first instance of TextView
    // you can also check if the title string matches
    if (child instanceof TextView) {
        toolbarTitle = (TextView)child;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this solution , And this is a following codes:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order History"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And you can change title/label , in Activity, write a below codes:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
```

TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText("@string/....");

Answer (score 4):

You can use like the following

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/top_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeToolbar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: if I set setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); to enalbe back arrow. Then title is not coming center. I have tried like setting actionBar.setTitle(""); and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false). But still not able to solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Update from @MrEngineer13's answer: to align title center in any cases, including Hamburger icon, option menus, you can add a `FrameLayout` in toolbar like this:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >

         <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Toolbar Title"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
               android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

        </FrameLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though adding a text view to the toolbar can solve the problem of the restriction of title styling, there is an issue with it. Since we are not adding it to a layout, we do not have too much control over its width. We can either use wrap_content or match_parent.

Now consider a scenario where we have a searchView as a button on the right edge of the toolbar. If the title contents are more, it will go on top of the button obscuring it. There is no way of controlling this short of setting a width to the label and is something you don't want to do if you want to have a responsive design.

So, here is a solution that worked for me which is slightly different from adding a textview to the toolbar. Instead of that, add the toolbar and text view to a relative layout and ensure that the text view is on top of the toolbar. Then we can use appropriate margins and make sure the text view shows up where we want it to show up.

Make sure you set the toolbar to not show the title.

Here is the XML for this solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                        android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.TitleTextView"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                        android:layoutMode="clipBounds">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                            android:id="@+id/search_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:foregroundTint="@color/white" />
                        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Solves the issue @ankur-chaudhary mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Since `android.support.v7.appcompat 24.2` `Toolbar` has method `setTitleTextAppearance` and you can set its font without external `textview`.

create new style in styles.xml

```
<style name="RobotoBoldTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_condensed_bold</item>
</style>
```

and use it

```
mToolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.RobotoBoldTextAppearance);
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent several days  searching for a universal solution. My toolbar working with android menu and nav icon.

At first, you need create custom toolbar class. This class must have calculate title centered positions (paddings):

```
    class CenteredToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : Toolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
            override fun onLayoutChange(v: View?, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, oldLeft: Int, oldTop: Int, oldRight: Int, oldBottom: Int) {
                val titleTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.centerTitle)

                val x = titleTextView.x.toInt()
                val x2 = x + titleTextView.width

                val fullWidth = width
                val fullCenter = fullWidth / 2

                val offsetLeft = Math.abs(fullCenter - x)
                val offsetRight = Math.abs(x2 - fullCenter)
                val differOffset = Math.abs(offsetLeft - offsetRight)

                if (offsetLeft > offsetRight) {
                    titleTextView.setPadding(differOffset, 0, 0, 0)
                } else if (offsetRight > offsetLeft) {
                    titleTextView.setPadding(0, 0, differOffset, 0)
                }

                removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun setTitle(resId: Int) = getTitleView().setText(resId)

    override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) = getTitleView().setText(title)

    fun getTitleView(): TextView = findViewById(R.id.centerTitle)

}
```

Secondly, you need create layout toolbar:

```
<CenteredToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</CenteredToolbar>
```

That's all

Answer (score 2):

**To use a custom title in your Toolbar  you can add a custom title like :**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnrTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txvHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Header"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Java Code:**

```java
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (getSupportActionBar() == null)
    return;

getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: the title bar has a spacing on left & right... what is that effect appeared?

Answer (score 2):

Try taking Toolbar and tittle in a separate view. Take a view on right end and given them weight equal to the toolbar weight. In this way your tittle will come in center.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@color/white_color">
  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/white_color">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white_color"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"

        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@color/greyTextColor">
       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <com.an.customfontview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/headingText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Heading"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/keyboard_number"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            app:textFontPath="fonts/regular.ttf" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/portfolio_icon"/>
        </LinearLayout>

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert this code in your xml file

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hi Uzair. Which xml file? I am using an Android Studio 3.6.3 Project created from an Empty Activity template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void makeTitleCenter(String title, Toolbar toolbar) {
    if (title != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title.trim())) {
        final String tag = " ";
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tag);
        }
        TextView titleTv = null;
        View leftBtn = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            CharSequence text = null;
            if (view instanceof TextView && (text = ((TextView) view).getText()) != null && text.equals(tag)) {
                titleTv = (TextView) view;
            } else if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
                leftBtn = view;
            }
        }
        if (titleTv != null) {
            final TextView fTitleTv = titleTv;
            final View fLeftBtn = leftBtn;
            fTitleTv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    fTitleTv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    int leftWidgetWidth = fLeftBtn != null ? fLeftBtn.getWidth() : 0;
                    fTitleTv.setPadding(DimenUtil.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2 - leftWidgetWidth - fTitleTv.getWidth() / 2, 0, 0, 0);
                    fTitleTv.requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for custom font in toolbar you can override textView font in style and then every textView in your app also toolbar title font changed automatically 
i tested it in **android studio 3.1.3**

in style do it:

```
<style name="defaultTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_custom_font</item>
</style>
```

and then in your theme use this:

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/defaultTextViewStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to add custom toolbar without any adicional Java/Kotlin code.

- First: create a XML with your custom toolbar layout with AppBarLayout as the parent:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout                     
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="80dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/magin_default"
          android:src="@drawable/logo" />

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  ```
- Second: Include the toolbar in your layout:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/blue"
      tools:context=".app.MainAcitivity"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

      <include
          layout="@layout/toolbar_inicio"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <!-- Put your layout here -->

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have two options:

1) Edit the toolbar XML. When your Toolbar is added in the XML it usually looks like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

if you want to customize it just remove the '/' in the end and make it like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_iv"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_iv"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

that way you can have a toolbar and customize the textview and the logo.

2) Programrticly change the native textview and icon:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_question_mark);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

**make sure your toolbar is not null before you set anything in it.**

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom `TextView` in the toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

So, this will center the text. If you want to add custom font to a normal `Toolbar`, make a `<style>`:

```
<style android:name="ToolbarFont">
    <item android:fontFamily = "@font/fontName" />
</style>
```

And add it to the toolbar:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.ToolbarFont);
```

For the textview in the toolbar, you can define it with the `fontFamily` attribute:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fontFamily" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, fixed by doing this in MainActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

And In Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
        init();
    }
    getActivity().setTitle("Choose Fragment");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          if(getTitle().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))) {
            super.onBackPressed();}
          else {
//set visiblity
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting `android:gravity="center"` worked for me**

No styling nothing. Toolbar is basically a `ViewGroup` all you need to do is set gravity of elements in it.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/partial_transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Does not work with `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did with one navigation icon and one Text view
now you can make an extension to apply it where ever you need it. but you have to apply it on every activity

```
(toolbar[0] as AppCompatTextView).let {
            it.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener {
                it.layoutParams = it.layoutParams.apply {
                    width = Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    (this as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).apply {
                        marginEnd = toolbar[1].width
                    }
                }
                it.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any one having this issue but using extra text view is bad because you have to manage title on your own and using reflection is worst because ids got change while adding progurad rules.
The most simple and accurate answer is using material toolbar which has the property to center the title.

```
app:titleCentered
```

Answer (score 0):

just apply this theme :

```
     <style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="navigationIconTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  @Composable
    fun topAppBar() {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    "Top App Bar"
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Back"
                    )
                }
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                        contentDescription = "More",
                    )
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You have to just add the below line in your toolbar layout:

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Answer (score -5):

```
Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font.ttf"); // your custom font
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTypeface(face);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Other Tutorial:

1. [Android Toolbar Example](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html)
2. [Using Custom Font in Android](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-android-application.html)
3. [ActionBar Tutorial with Example](http://viralandroid.com/search/label/ActionBar)

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar class doesn't have setTypeface method.