# Toolbar not scrolling when using collapsing toolbar effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using below layout to use collapsing toolbar effect but not able to expand toolbar.I want to expand the toolbar as given here for collapsing toolbar effect.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Guide me with any corrections.

Comment: follow standard docs : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: And view pager is not like list or scroll view, so toolbar wont work like this. You need to specify it in the fragments where you have used recycler view or nested scrollview.

Comment: [Related info about the `NestedScrollView`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30646837/383414) that @Harry mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the view with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` has to be scrollable vertically, which `ViewPager` is not. I am not quite sure whether wrapping the `ViewPager` into some `ScrollView` would help. Most probably it would cause some problems with touch event handling. If the page within your `ViewPager` is scrollable, you should set the `app:layout_behavior` directly to its scrollable view but I am not sure this would work as expected either. The collapsing toolbar effect is not meant to work this way and it is not yet perfect even when used as intended.

Comment: `ScrollView` does not support this, but there is a [`NestedScrollView` that will support it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30646837/383414).

Answer (score 0):

Use design support library http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

include this in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'    
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+'
```

for recycler view include this also

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

```
    <!-- AppBarLayout allows your Toolbar and other views (such as tabs provided by TabLayout) 
    to react to scroll events in a sibling view marked with a ScrollingViewBehavior.-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- specify tag app:layout_scrollFlags -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <!-- specify tag app:layout_scrollFlags -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <!--  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" will help to pin this view at top when scroll -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This will be your scrolling view. 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tag connects this features -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Your activity should extend **AppCompatActivity**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        //set toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

}
```

Your app theme should be like this

```
    <resources>
            <!-- Base application theme. -->   
            <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            </style>
    </resources>
```