# Custom Action Bar in Android does not match parent

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

Hello everyone I'm try to make custom action bar. My codes below. Everything is good at the right side of Action Bar but at the left side custom action bar does not match. How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in helpings.

[image]

**EDIT 1 :** 
My main activity xml, it has not got anything interest with action bar but I could not figure out where the problem is

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"              tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/hh">

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my custom action bar xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="#ffff2301" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
}

}
```

Comment: Can u upload the xml of your main activity?

Comment: And it looks like the black space is a kind of space for the menu button

Comment: Thank for comment. I've edited my question. And dont find anything concerned about action bar.

Comment: Please turn on the option showLayoutBounda in your developet settings on your smartphone. Then we can see why you have this ugly space there ;)

Comment: Thanks again but i dont know how can I do that :S It is emulator screen.

Comment: Oh. I dont know where you can do it in the emulator. I only know it on the device itself but have you tried to give the actionbar itself a background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `setCustomView()` on the default toolbar provided by the theme. Custom views are meant to be loaded in the toolbar space that is **not** occupied by other views (logo, title, overflow menu..).

So your custom layout becomes *part* of the toolbar, and does not replace it. So either:

1. You want things to be this way. In this case your issue is just background color. I don't know how you set the custom view to be yellow, but try adding `android:background="@color/transparent"` to the `RelativeLayout` and switch the whole toolbar color to yellow instead. The room in the left will be eventually loaded with navigation icons, so you want it to be there.
2. You want to (I'd suggest to) use the `Toolbar` API which makes it easier to add custom views. This is done this way:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>


       <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

       </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

And then, in custom_toolbar.xml,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:abc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- you can add any custom view here -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#ffff2301" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your `onCreate()` you now have to call:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, is first xml file will be my main activity xml ?

Comment: You did it it like a charm bro :) Thank you. But I'm wondering. How can I set titlebar center.

Comment: Just add a textview with the attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"`, this question has been answered [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/4288782)