# Android - Center the title of the Toolbar

Tags: java, android, title, toolbar

i have a Toolbar in my app like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#263355"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And i add the title as that:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

I've read that [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

But if i change the xml of the toolbar, i don't know how to change the value of the TextView. Someone can help me ?

Comment: Use that other answer, and use findViewById to get the TextView

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do not use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);` to set the title, if you have a custom Toolbar layout.

Instead, assuming your XML layout looks like this:

```
        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You need to call, somewhere in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` probably:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title)).setText("Title!");
```

Comment: Awesome solution @Karim