# How to center the title of a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I tried `setExpandTitleTextAppearance`, but it didn't work. I want to center the expanded title text.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already, its easier to 'help' that way

Answer (score 79):

There is an attribute `expandedTitleGravity` that you can use with the CollapsingToolbarLayout to center the expanded title text. Add this to your CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: smart answer :)

Comment: @androholic, How about the `app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal`, Which actually doesn't work

Answer (score 23):

In my use case, I set `app:titleEnabled` to false, I didn't need it anyway.  After that, my gravity was respected properly inside the Toolbar layout.

Comment: I wanted my custom toolbar to show title in the center. by setting up this property in CollapsingToolbarLayout helped me with my requirement.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

> you can arrange the position of the tittle in both the collapsed and
>   expanded state in the following ways

in expanded state,

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
```

in collapsed state,

```
app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
```

i think this may help you

Comment: the problem is, in `collapsed` state, the title is improperly horizontally centered. there's a padding/margin from the left. *Edit*: turns out, you can fix it by adding `android:paddingEnd:24dp` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: @Ace `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765551/collapsingtoolbarlayout-center-textview-in-toolbar

Answer (score 4):

@Javed, correct me if I wrong, you want to have the title centered in the Toolbar, then CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed and your layout is something like this, right?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Then you can do this trick ( i do it in onCreate of the Activity):

```
    try {
        Field declaredField = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) declaredField.get(toolbar);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = titleTextView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        titleTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        titleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //"Error!"
    }
```

The key is that TextView within Toolbar has width property "Wrap Content", so we need to change it to "Match Parent".
(See more about this reflection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font))

Tested on Android 5.1.1 and Android 4.3 (should work pretty much everywhere)

Comment: I happen to be working on the same issue. Centering a custom title `TextView` in a `Toolbar` seems like it should work, but for some reason `layout_gravity="center"` does not center the text in this scenario. The `TextView`'s text gets right-aligned instead. Potentially a bug.

Comment: @Ryan great catch, love it! Fixed my answer and tested it on android 5.1.1 and android 4.3. Thanks for notice!

Comment: your updated answer looks like it should work, but I hate to have to resort to using reflection. Too bad there isn't a more streamlined approach to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Nguyễn Hoàng Anh said above, set `app:titleEnabled` to false worked like a charm.

With that option enabled, after some digging with the layout inspector,  suspicious unnamed-view is always added in front of `TextView` inside of `Toolbar`, just after 'Up' button(if it is enabled).

So even though layout gravity is working correctly, some suspicious view takes over all extra spaces inside of the `Toolbar`.

Comment: It kills the animation of the title.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to centre the title in the collapsed state you can use

```
android:paddingEnd="70dp"
android:paddingRight="70dp"
```

like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingEnd="70dp"
            android:paddingRight="70dp"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"        
            app:expandedTitleGravity="start"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: It added the extra spaces from the right sides which are not good as best practice

Answer (score 0):

include this in collapsing toolbar xml 
for collapsed :
`app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

for expanded
`app:expandedTitleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`