# CollapsingToolbarLayout center TextView in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want toolbar_title layout center in toolbar, but itlooks like there is some margin on left, if I remove CollapsingToolbarLayout it is ok.
Inorder to center toolbar_title text I set toolbar_title's margin right manualy in code, but the only after the fragment resumed I toolbar_title.getX() can get the correct value, so I postDelayed 50 ms to do this.

now ther is the question:
how to center toolbar_title in CoordinatorLayout on a better way?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToolBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="title"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add below attributes in your Toolbar.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

See similar thread on stackoverflow: [Android API 21 Toolbar Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding)

See title textview position before and after attributes adding in toolbar.

**Before adding attributes:**

[image: Before adding attributes]

**After adding attributes:**

[image]

Comment: It works if there is no homeAsUpIndicator, when show homeAsUpIndicator title still on the right

Comment: @qinqie What about `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`?