# Android ActionBar -- How to add logo in centrelly aligned

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new in android development and I want make a navigation drawer for my client.

How can I add a logo to my action bar in navigation drawer and remove the title.

my code :

**Activity**

```
 public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#D5D2D4")));
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
```

**Manifest Activity**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activity.Grid_Home_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_grid__home_"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ActionBarJp">
    </activity>
```

**Styles**

```
<style name="Theme.ActionBarJp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar is deprecated. Use [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) .
Then at your *Toolbar* object center the ImageView with the logo.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: where is the image part ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint this Library 
and use as below.

```
 public ActionBar enableCustomCenterTitle(Context context, boolean isShowBack, boolean isWhite) {
    ActionBar actionBar = enableCustomTitle();

    View actionbarLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.actionbar_layout, (ViewGroup) actionBar.getCustomView(),false);
    if (isWhite) {
        actionbarLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_layout_white, (ViewGroup) actionBar.getCustomView(),false);
        TextView back = (TextView) actionbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_back);
        back.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        mTintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        setStatusBarDarkMode(true, this);
    }
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new
            ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

    View backView = ButterKnife.findById(actionbarLayout, R.id.action_bar_back);
    if (isShowBack) {
        backView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        backView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        backView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionbarLayout, params);
    return actionBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setLogo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setLogo(int)) to set a `resDrawable` or `Drawable` object. As to the logo size on the ActionBar, I believe it's 32x32 dp; Optical square, 24x24 dp according to [this](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

To remove the title, just use `actionBar.setTitle("")`. This code makes it looks like there is no title.

One more thing, You should really change `ActionBar` to [`ToolBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

Answer (score 0):

As actionbar is deprecated, it is better to user [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) and can utilize [material design concepts](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) in your app.

Do according below:
1. create `toolbar.xml` in your `res`  folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/grey"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_Logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2. Open the layout file of your main activity (activity_main.xml) and add the toolbar.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical">

   <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       layout="@layout/toolbar" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. In your `MainActivity.java`, add reference of Toolbar widget in `onCreate()` method :

   ```
   mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   ```

Comment: I am using navigation drawer, is it any issues with using the toolbar

Comment: no, it would works properly. also go through this link :http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ , it will solve your problem.