# How to remove app title from toolbar?

Tags: android

I can't figure out how to remove my title. I've used the code below in my `MainActivity` but after I added that line, my app crashes.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Here is how my MainActivity looks:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Full code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
```

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: Please post your full code of `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method.

Comment: Yes okay let me edit my question

Comment: can you please provide your logcat too?

Comment: layout and theme should be added first. @yoshatabi

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` actually solved my issue. I needed to set a title so that the app would show up in the recent apps list so `android:label=""` was not an option.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try this,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
```

If still doesn't works just use **setNavigationIcon()** & **setLogo()** and that should replace the title. If you are facing any crashes please post the crash report.

Comment: I Accepted it! Have nice day yourself

Comment: how do you center the logo you set?

Comment: @Lion789 try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: I did, the problem with that is that it looks at the space available, I need it to ignore that, because when I have two icons the space available is not going to allow me to center the imageview properly

Comment: This did not worked for me.
Setting `android:label=""` in Activity tag of Manifest worked.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use toolbar.setTitle(""); 
Or you can simply set the android:label="" for your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Using `android:label=""` is not a good idea. If you have an `<intent-filter>` on that Activity to allow users to open your app by clicking a URL (for example), the disambiguation dialog will not have any title!

Answer (score 2):

This is my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zumoappname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

and this is my activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 .....
```

The following code works very nice for me:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
myToolbar.setTitle("");
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your styles.xml

Change your theme to .NoActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is just important

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Write this{   } in manifest file.

Comment: This does not match https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096547/7733418 so what are you talking about? Do you even attempt to answer the question? Or is this only "Thanks"? Even if somewhat mistaken for what. If you cannot [edit] this into an answer according to [answer] please delete it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).