# Why Application name shown by it self in app bar? And how to remove it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i created a blank app bar in an activity, inserted a text and everything was working fine, i modified the code a little and now the application name shown in the app bar, how to remove it and where did it come from? 
[here is the design and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2b8v.jpg)

and here the code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096517/3981656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to remove title from action bar try this**

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

**try this to change actionbar title**

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");// set your title name
```

Comment: worked nice and clear(much appreciated), may i know what was the error?

Comment: I see, your answer was very helpful but i don't have the required reputation to accept answers yet, sorry.

Comment: @All_Rounder no need of reputation just mark my ans as correct

Comment: oh sorry, i am still a newbie, i got this "You have reached your question limitIt looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!", can you tell me what was wrong with my question? so i can ask better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Add label to your activity in manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/name_you_want"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/Apollo.Landing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```