# Android set custom font in title Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, custom-font

I want to change the font of my custom toolbar.

My problem is that this isn't a static textview. I tried to use a Spannable String like this:

```
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "font.otf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(s);
```

But it won't works :-(
In the pics you can see how it looks like...

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4066/ye8tcshb_png.htm

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4066/oh7t6ddv_png.htm

Thanks for answering :-)

Comment: hi, take a look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
TextView newfont;
newfont=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
newfont.setTypeface(font);
newfont.setText("This is the new font Text");
```

Of course put the `font.ttf` file inside `assets/fonts` folder.

Note that `TextView` inside `Toolbar` is just like any other `TextView`.

[Read more from here](http://javatechig.com/android/using-external-fonts-in-android-view)

Comment: Ok yes, this works but that was what I have tried before, yet :-D ehm the problem is that the textview isn't dynamically. In other words, if i scroll down the text appears but if I scroll up the text disappears. It should work like: The text like picture one and if I scroll up in the listview, the text appears in the ActionBar...

EDIT:
Ok i think I solved this in the xml to put layout_gravity to "bottom". :-)