# How to center Title toolbar from within FRAGMENT on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

For a specific design I want to have Toolbar title text centered.

I haven't been able to get it working from within a **fragment**, although
I have managed to do this in an **activity** by following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font) where I create a custom toolbar widget with 2 textviews for the toolbar and set this as the SupportActionBar adding the toolbar's xml as an include in the activity's layout xml. Something like this:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarCouponDetailed);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_coupons_title);
    TextView toolbarTitleDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_coupons_title_date_text);
    toolbarTitle.setText(StringUtils.onlyFirstLetterUpperCase(mCoupon.getRetailerName()));
    toolbarTitleDate.setText(mCoupon.getDateTxt());

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

I tried to use the same approach but somehow I just can seem to get it working.
Does anyone have an idea or a code sample solving this issue?

Edit:
I've actually created another toolbar layout for the fragment that I include in the fragments xml. In onCreateView() I've created a member variable to create a reference to the toolbar, that I then can use onActivityCreated() where I call:

```
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

But the activities toolbar is still used this way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android toolbar center title and custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: @Boss: Yes I read that post as well, but as explained I managed to solve the issue of centering title in the toolbar of an activity, but my issue here concerns centering the title of the toolbar from within a FRAGMENT

Comment: Simply use another toolbar layout just for that fragment - would that work for you?

Comment: Are you able to access `toolbar` inside `Fragment` ?

Comment: I've actually created another toolbar layout for the fragment that I include in the fragments xml. In onCreateView() I store a specific reference to the toolbar, that I then can use onActivityCreated() where I call:
  .setSupportActionBar(mToolbar), .getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); & .getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) on ((MainActivity) getActivity())


But the activities toolbar is still used this way

Answer (score 0):

No Need to create another `toolbar` for `fragment` because Toolbar is part pf `Actvity` and fragment too. there is only one Toolbar should be there

use below method in every `fragment` or create `BaseFragment` and call method from `onCreate()`

```
protected void setTitleFragment(String strTitle){
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView txtTitle =((TextView)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title));
    txtTitle.setText(strTitle);
}
```