# How to get title at center of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to get the title of the Collapsed Toolbar to the center. But there seems to be some bug in the basic layout itself. The title has an offset for some reason.
Unable to figure out how to fix this. Also there seems to be no property to apply negative margin/padding to the collapsedTitle.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/XXXXAppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top|center_horizontal"
        app:expandedTitleMarginTop="-10dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="REGISTER">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/XXXXAppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/white_background"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: CollapsedToolbar]

Comment: This is iOS style. Please don't make Android an iOS :)

Comment: Well, unable to argue with my manager. This is what is needed unfortunately. :)

Comment: The offset appears to be because of the up navigation button. If you really want to do this, it's best to use a custom layout and add a toolbar therein. It will give you complete control over the design.

However, I agree with @Sufian. This is very iOS. :)

Comment: if you just select your toolbar in xml editor preview you will find that there is a certain offset in it. To remove that you will have to use custom toolbar or either shift your register text to left accordingly

Answer (score 5):

Try this within your "`Toolbar`"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/color"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Register"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: How to get rid of the default title?

Comment: remove "app:title" from your xml on the CollapsingToolbar, if that does not work, then set the text of the CollapsingToolbar to "" in your code

Comment: @iZBasit check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

To make it centered, please follow the steps:

> To use a custom title in your `Toolbar` all you need to do is remember
>   is that `Toolbar` is just a fancy ViewGroup so you can add a custom
>   title like so:
>
> ```
>  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar       
>   android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>   android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
>   app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >
>
>
>    <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Toolbar Title"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
>
>
>   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
> ```
>
> This means that you can style the `TextView` however you would like
>   because it's just a regular `TextView`. So in your activity you can
>   access the title like so:
>
> ```
> Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
> TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
> ```
>
> From: [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

To remove the default app name title, do this:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar_top); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Hope it help

Comment: Please update your answer with the link where you took this from :)

Comment: @piotrek1543 how will it do the scaling, if I use a custom textview?

Comment: @scaling of what? maybe `android:textsize`, `android:textScaleX`, `android:scaleX`, `android:scaleY`

Comment: @piotrek1543 I am using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will the collapse animation be supported when I add a `TextView` as you have suggested?

Comment: just give it a try and tell me, I don't have any idea about it, but I feel that yes

Answer (score -1):

You should use this. To add `TextView` in side `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```