# Where is it setting the initial toolbar code on Android?

Tags: android, toolbar

If you use Android Studio and set up and application, it sets up the default title of the `toolbar` to be the name of the activity. Where is the code for that? Also, I want to orient the `items` in toolbar the way I would like them to be. Where can I write codes for that? Is it in the xml file of menu or in layout file of the activity? I've tried setting text to center in the layout of the activity but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change de title setting app_name in strings.xml file.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Toolbar Title</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the code for that?

is in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity  
    android:name="com.example.loginandregisterapi.LoginActivity"  
    android:label="@string/app_name" >  <!-- THIS -->
    ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you use Android Studio and set up and application, it sets up the
>   default title of the toolbar to be the name of the activity. Where is
>   the code for that?

Take a look at your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You'll probably find two `android:label` attributes there: one for the application and another one for the launcher activity. And they'll be pointing to a single string resource `@string/app_name`, which is located in `strings.xml` of your module's res folder. You can change the `app_name` value or put the name right in `android:label` attribute. Label from `<application>` tag will be shown on the Settings screen while `<activity>` label will be put on your launcher. The same applies to `android:icon` attribute.

> Also, I want to orient the items in toolbar the way I would like them
>   to be. Where can I write codes for that? Is it in the xml file of menu
>   or in layout file of the activity?

Yes, you can add Back button to the left of your title and all the option menu items will be sticked to the right. Back button should be added in you `MainActivity.java` after setting action bar: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. Put all your menu items in `res/menu/menu_main.xml` and they will appear on the right side of your toolbar.

> I've tried setting text to center in the layout of the activity but it
>   doesn't work.

Toolbar isn't designed to be customizable, so you'll need a bit of hacking. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font) or implement custom view instead of default toolbar to match your requirements.

[Additional reading.](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)