# customizing android toolbar programmatically

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to use android v7.toolbar in my project with fragments. So  i did something like below in my main activity xml. Because i dont want to add all fragments xml to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar" />

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i am adding fragments with programmatically. And in some fragments i have to change right side of the toolbar. For example in some fragments i have to use just 1 right menu icon and another fragments 2. How can i achieve it?

Also is there a way to change icon resource which is in right side of the toolbar from fragments?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `menu.xml` and put all your menu items in it. Set all the items `visibility` to `false`. This hides everything.

Then in your fragment's `onCreate` set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`, this will allow you to override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m, MenuInflater inflater)`.

In this method you can do `menu.findItem(id.of.item).setVisible(true/false)`.

Examples:

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.sample.app.MainActivity">    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_edit_account"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_enable_offline_token"
        android:orderInCategory="105"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_enable_offline_token"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_disable_offline_token"
        android:orderInCategory="105"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_disable_offline_token"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="106"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);        
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_save).setVisible(true);
    }
```

To change icons you can just get the menu and do a findItem and setIcon.

Comment: thank you so much. Are you also know how to center a text in v7.toolbar? @ChoklatStu

Comment: [For centering text check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)