# Centering Title in Custom Toolbar

Tags: android

I have created a custom toolbar with an image as a centered title and another aligned to the right. I have used a relative layout to house the imageviews. But the relative layout doesn't seem to cover the entire length of the toolbar despite its width being set to match_parent. The code is as follows:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/title"
                android:id="@+id/title_image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/oie_transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/cart_icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // an example activity_main.xml is provided below
        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
    }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: It does not include a relative layout and multiple children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar bearing left and right must thoroughly justify otherwise remain a 5DP like an open left side. The following code : img left justified and right -justified img title has centered on.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarhome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center|left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bes"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/beyaz"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/actiontitle"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/msr"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/bes" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```