# Toolbar title not in center when Back Button is enable

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to display my toolbar title in the center and to do it I use the method which is given in this answer :-[Toolbar Center title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/4169014)

However, when I enable back button in my `activity` by following code:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

The title of toolbar doesn't show up in the center but slightly off-centered towards the right.

How can I achieve centered title **without** being **affected by the back button or menu bar?**

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Add a TextView inside the Toolbar & don't forget to set the following attribute inside your TextView.

> android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" 
>   
>   **OR** 
>   android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

code snippet:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Refer to [this](http://sourcey.com/android-custom-centered-actionbar-with-material-design/) tutorial for more information.

Comment: android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize" also works great

Comment: You need to use `android:layout_gravity="center"` & `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for `TextView`. There is no. need for `android:layout_marginRight` or something else.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko If you do that then you’l notice that the text is slightly positioned towards the right instead of exactly center when back button is visible(as it is being centered from the available space). So, this is just a workaround.

Comment: Maybe I`m blind but it is not true.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko hahaha..i just tried on Android studio it was still leaving space towards left..why don’t you post an answer maybe it might help someone.

Comment: @JohnnyFive The title starts at 72dp when the back button is visible & by default there's a toolbar margin end of 16dp. So, ?actionBarSize (56dp) + default toolbar end margin(16dp) = 72dp. You could directly mention 56dp instead of actionBarSize. Refer this [link](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#specs) for design guidelines.

Comment: How to implement it without a toolbar.

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive You can make use of Linear Layout or Relative Layout instead of toolbar to make it look like a toolbar and customize it based on your needs.

Comment: @Arshak  I am using the action bar and textview is programmatically included where I am using Linearlayout still it is not centered. In my action bar "home button, title, menu" are present. How to work on it?

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive AFAIK Action bar got deprecated with API 21. Please make use of Toolbar which could resolve your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Having a placeholder image the same size as the back arrow and setting it to be ***invisible*** when the back arrow is ***not shown*** and ***gone*** when it's ***displayed*** did the trick for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_actionbar_hamburger"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="normal"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:paddingEnd="72dp;` to the Toolbar layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:paddingEnd="72dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:title="Title"/>
```

Comment: make marginEnd or paddingEnd 72dp instead 64dp to be exact. i recent findout on closer inspection

Answer (score 2):

Just put your content in a child view inside the Toolbar tag in XML, using the following attributes:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Offical docs for Toolbar state:

> One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of Gravity#CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

This works for me, using androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar with a child view.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the title is not centered when you use a back button as navigation icon, is that navigation icon is represented as `AppCompatImageButton` and is added to the same layout as your title `TextView`. Using [Arshak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582618/2658949) is not a bad idea, but `?android:attr/actionBarSize` is not a good way to define the end margin. As the action bar height is probably the same size as icon's width, it might work, but might not work on all devices. Could be a good idea to specify this size from [material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#specs).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using an imageview inside the toolbar which I didnt want shifting around while navigating between fragments of a activity.
I kept it centered by placing it out the toolbar. I used constraintlayouts

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



</com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
 ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the nicest and most up-to-date method is to have full control over the appbar. This way you can change other things from textview location.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can use this directly inside your activity. However, you may need to change the active toolbar by making such a definition in the activity where you added this toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont set propterties like this

```
mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Do like this

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.themeToolbarColor));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();  // to go back  finish() will do your work.
                //mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                //mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```