# Custom Toolbar side textView which is in the end of Toolbar title got detached when back button or hamberger Button is enable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

[image]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semi_bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/layout_main_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
                    tools:text="Toolbar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_job_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_blue_gradient_with_thirty_radius"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:text="1425"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_7ssp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

In this project, I use Navigation Component. I want to show the number in blue border beside the "Job Board". I took a look at this solution.
[Toolbar title not in center when Back Button is enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582331/toolbar-title-not-in-center-when-back-button-is-enable) 
.That solution abled to solve the problem of centering the toolbar text to center but not the Number. 
I want this type of output
[image]

Comment: set android:gravity="center" for your otal_job_text_view

Comment: Post an image of the back button in display

Comment: @GiddyNaya actually it wiil detached when hamberger button or back button is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. The main culprit was contentinsetstart which take 72 dp as padding in the beginning of Toolbar which size is 72 dp. so what I did, I just gave a negative 72 margin in toolbarTextView. And everything is running as expected :)

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-72dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semi_bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/layout_main_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
                    tools:text="Toolbar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_job_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_blue_gradient_with_thirty_radius"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:text="1425"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_7ssp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and destinationChangeListener looks exactly like

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id != R.id.tutorHomeFragment) {
                total_job_text_view.visibilityGone()
            }

            with(toolbar_text_view) {
                when(destination.id) {
                    R.id.tutorHomeFragment -> text = getString(R.string.job_board)
                    R.id.tutorProfileFragment -> text = getString(R.string.profile)
                    R.id.tutorStatusFragment -> text = getString(R.string.status)
                    R.id.tutorSettingFragment -> text = getString(R.string.settings)
                    R.id.tutorMessageFragment -> text = getString(R.string.message)
                    R.id.confirmationLetterFragment -> text = getString(R.string.confirmation_letter)
                    R.id.paymentFragment -> text = getString(R.string.payment)
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your textView

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
```

this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try removing **android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"**  and use **alignParentLeft=true** or layout_margenStart.
hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your toolbar text margin to something smaller.

> > @+id/toolbar_text_view

```
  android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

To

```
 android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
```

Comment: if I do so, toolbar text will not place in center when navigation back button is shown

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you must constraint layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.ui.zzzzActivity">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tulisan20sp"
            tools:text="Toolbar"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_job_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_text_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen8dp"
            android:text="1425"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**UPDATE**
if you want the number not visible in fragment you can set visible :invisible and text in always center:
[image: this xml]

you can set programatically :

```
textview.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE)
```

don't

```
textview.setVisible(View.GONE)
```

if you want set visible :

```
textview.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: If I use Constraint Layout, its easy to centralized one textView. But when I navigate to another fragment, number textView must be hidden in my app. Then without the number textView it does not seem in center. That's the actual problem

Comment: your setvisible(View.Invisible). not setvisible(View.Gone).
if you set Gone, the view is gone. but if you set invisible, the view not gone and not visible. may be you can try when  textview is hidden

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. But I also tried that. It will make other toolbar text center except the one with number text View :(

Answer (score 0):

**remove line from TextView:-**

```
android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

**Add this line in Relativelayout:-**

```
android:layout_marginStart="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

hope it will work.

Comment: It also failed to fulfill my expected result :(