# how to align icon on the left side of the app bar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appbar

I am trying to push the back icon image on the left side of the app bar in the android but the icon displaying in the middle of app(tool) bar. How to align icon on the right side of the app bar in android? Please have a look at the image below.

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="divine.calcify.activities.HomeScreenActivity">
    <item
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:id="@+id/hs_back_button"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_back"
        android:title="@string/homescreen_back"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        ></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/homescreen_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_notifications"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_divine_notification"
        android:title="@string/homescreen_notification"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Use Toolbar and set getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); for toolbar

Comment: do you want just the back icon on left or you want both back icon and hamburger icon together??

Comment: @MujammilAhamed i tried what you suggested but not working

Comment: @himanshu1496 i want both with back icon at the left most of the app bar.

Comment: then you need to customise the toolbar with your layout and also you need to handle the clicks by yourself.

Comment: Check this to add your own toolbar http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/5515371

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically add back button in java file (in `Activity`)

Try this

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setTitle("Divine");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`. `Toolbar` gives you freedom to design it freely as normal view.

If you dont have implemented toolbar yet no problem.

1. Extend you class to `ActionBarActivity`
2. Update theme with parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

   `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
           <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
           <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
           <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
           <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
       </style>`
3. Create your toolbar layout.

   ```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:minHeight="100dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


       <!--your views here-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```
4. `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

[**Full Demo Here**](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html)