# Toolbar title in Fragments

Tags: android

How can i change `Textview` inside `Toolbar` when Fragments are changed? My toolbar is in a `BaseActivity`, so i could use in all activities.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        ndroid:layout_marginRight="attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


                </FrameLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily change title using this line:

```
((MyAppCompatBaseActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello World!");
```

**Edit:**

I just saw that you have a `TextView` inside your `Toolbar`. So to set the title do this in your BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewTitle;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Other Code
        textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        textViewTitle.setText(title);
    }

}
```

Then in your Fragment just do this:

```
((BaseActivity)getActivity()).setTitle("Hello World!");
```

Comment: that didnt worked. cuz my fragments are in tab layout and it gave title to all my fragments the same title

Comment: it seems like working but not updating the title if i change the fragments for e.x from 1st to 2nd or from 3rd to 2nd. why?

Comment: Keep this line `((BaseActivity)getActivity()).setTitle("Hello World!");` in your Fragment's `onResume()`.

Comment: of course yes that should work, really hate fragments

Answer (score 0):

> Simply you can do this inside your `onCreateView()` method.

```
getActivity().setTitle("Your Title");
```

**EDIT 1:**

> For making `title` in `center` you need to make your `layout` like below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="LOGO"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: how to make it in garavity(center) than

Comment: @AlimovShohrukh Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Answer (score 0):

Make `textView` and toolbar as public in your `BaseActivity`. Now use the following code in your fragment.

```
((BaseActivity)getActivity()).yourTextView.setText("HOME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add to Your Code

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Yeeee");
```

Comment: it's better if explain something more in the answer... it could be very much more useful to future users having the same problem...

Comment: I would recommend expanding your answer.

Comment: Probably duplicate of @Eric B. answer above. Which is indeed the correct answer

Comment: This answer is definitely a duplicate.