# How to align content in a Toolbar center even with menu items

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a centered view in `Toolbar`. When I add `MenuItem`s, the content gets pushed so it's is not centered. I know `ActionMenuView` is an option but SearchView doesn't expand this time (another question). I've tried `contentInset` attributes but no luck.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ugurlogo_white" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the result. Red view is the `FrameLayout`. I want the `FrameLayout` to match `Toolbar` width.

[image: Toolbar]

How am I gonna achieve this?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: I know how to center it "without menu items"