# change navigation bar title position in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

How to change the position of the navigation bar `title` in **Xamarin.Forms**.

What i get in default is:

[image]

What i want is:

[image]

How can i do this in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: For Android you mean?

Comment: for both android and ios...can it be done in xamarin forms?

Comment: For iOS the title is in the middle by default, right? It can be done in Forms, but you will have to use a custom renderer. Or make it work for just Android with a theme or layout or something.

Comment: Can you please help me by giving the custom renderer example?

Comment: There is not even a need for a custom renderer for Android, check out [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59722/toolbar-title-set-center-align) on the Xamarin Forums.

Comment: check the follwing link : https://gist.github.com/jimmgarrido/69fa7266fa5d824cb9d5a99274809668#file-navigationpagerenderer-cs-L29

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font here is the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Xamarin.forms app based on [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) then you can easily achieve this using [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar), define your title content, bind it or even style it as you like.

Inside your `ContentPage`:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Your Title" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

You will avoid you to use a custom renderer.

Also if you need to apply some special platform-dependent adjustments you can use [OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform).