# How can I edit the header in a blank activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm very new to android studio but I can't see any XML of the header, so I can't edit it. I want to do things like change it's position, height etc so is there any way I can do this?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.zorgan.app.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "header" ?

Comment: Wasn't aware it's called Toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add ToolBar to your activity:

1) **Create** a new **layout** called `new_activity_main.xml` and add the following code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 <!-- include your activity_main.xml here  -->

 <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Create a **style** to disable ActionBar in **style.xml** :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

3) **Set** this style to your Activity in **manifest**:

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

4) Set **layout** of activity:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.new_activity_main);
```

5) And add the following code to onCreate(). First initiate toolbar then disable default title:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps. (Kudos to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/7235049) answer).

Comment: There is no XML for the toolbar though so I can't edit it. My XML is in my edit.

Comment: Where did you search ? activity_main.xml ? Try find in app_bar_main.xml. Or you are using ActionBar ? Can you confirm please ?

Comment: Alright I get it, you are using ActionBar. Wait a moment.

Comment: This is just a blank activity, so the toolbar is automatically added. I'm not sure whether it's ActionBar or not and I don't think i have app_bar_main.xml

Comment: First tell me are you sure want to continue with ActionBar ? Cause ActionBar is deprecated. You can add Toolbar very easily. I can show you both - Showing ActionBar Styling or Toolbar Addition process ? Your choice :)

Comment: Adding Toolbar.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'm adding the procedure please wait a moment.

Comment: I've added the whole process. Please check.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it out now. Does that also remove my current ToolBar? (the one that automatically comes with BlankActivity)

Comment: Yes, it will replace the previous one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138278/discussion-between-zorgan-and-tahsinrupam).

Comment: cannot resolve class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: I replaced it to android.widget.Toolbar : it is available from android API v21

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the name and simple stuff go to the AndroidManifest.xml file under application tag you can change basic things.

If you are talking about the Toolbar, you can check this tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `setTitle("any");`below setContentView in your activity