# Custom Toolbar Title not work correctly

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, titlebar

i'm trying to set i Custom Toolbar Title from here : 
[Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

But title is still appear like below picture :

[image]

Here is Toolbar XML :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

JAVA :

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    /*Start Font Face*/
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Limelight.ttf");
    mTitle.setTypeface(tf);
    /*Rnd Font Face */
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("")` to hide default `title`.

**Try this:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Limelight.ttf");
mTitle.setTypeface(tf);
mTitle.setText("ARTISTIC");
```

Comment: Use mTitle.setText("NEW TITLE") instead of mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());