# ActionBar icon and text different colors

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want make an action bar but back indicator and text has to be different colors. How can I achieve this?

[image]

When I use this:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.back));
```

it becomes something weird:
enter image description here

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq38b.png)

The picture I'm using is this: 
[image]

Comment: aren't they already different in the image you attached ?

Comment: For this you have to create custom Toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use image for back button as :

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getDrawable(R.drawable.back))
```

and for title text color you have make changes in your theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightRed</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, Put this code inside your `onCreate()` of the activity :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffff00'>Your Title</font>"));
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getDrawable(R.drawable.back_button));
```

If you are facing issue with `getSupportActionBar()` use `getActionBar()`

or, you can create a custom toolbar  to achieve this :

**Look into this :** [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

**For fixing your image issue you can go with below sites :**

Download any backimage from this site and put in mipmap/drawable folder of android studio all 5 images for different size. https://materialdesignicons.com/

**Or,** Use this site to **convert your image in 5 different sizes** :
 [romannurik.github.io](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

[image]

Comment: I can't use getDrawable because my API level is 19 and when I use 
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.back)); it makes something weird which I shared in main post

Comment: Are you using custom ActionBar ? & i update my answer look @MehmetKemalBayer

Comment: getActionBar() returns null

Comment: Make sure have you imported import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

Comment: Hello, @MehmetKemalBayer, your issue is only with back image gets bigger or any more issue ?