# How to put Label to the center?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to put the label of my app to the center. By default its aligned to the left.

Label is the word CAIN which is shown here,

[image: Label is the word CAIN which is shown here].

How can I do that?
Here is the code of AndroidManifest.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.khurshidyakubov.cain">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

    **android:label="@string/app_name"**

    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: where you set te lable on `textview`. and this `textview` give the `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your MainActivity,

```
      ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
      TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

      LayoutParams lps = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

      textview.setLayoutParams(lps);

      textview.setText("CAIN");

      textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      textview.setTextSize(22);
      actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
      actionbar.setCustomView(textview);
```