# How can i set Toolbar title using Retrofit android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, toolbar

I used CollapsingToolbarLayout and try to set dynamically Toolbar Title using retrofit but it is not working. just look at my code :-

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getApiService();
    Call<GetAttributesResponse> call = api.getAttributes(27, attributId);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetAttributesResponse>() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetAttributesResponse> call, @NonNull Response<GetAttributesResponse> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                        titleName = response.body().getData().getAttributeName();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleName);
                        toolbar.setTitle(titleName);
                    }
                }

        }
```

My Xml Code Structure:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

         <ImageView
         </ImageView>
         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: did you check whether the API response is a success?  Try debugging and check whether `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleName);` this is working.

Comment: Show xml file which contain toolbar. and instead of using `toolbar.setTitle` use TextView which you have added in custom toolbar for title

Comment: @MilanJoseph I already check getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleName); not work and API Response is working.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i added my XML formet please look at my question and if possible give me ans thank you.

Comment: @HitechP: Add title TextView in `Toolbar` . see [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: you did not specify any attribute of toolbar in xml..so it will not be visible to you.

Comment: post your xml here..structure of xml is not enough to understand the actual problem

Comment: I done using collapsingToolbar.setTitle(titleName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this :**

```java
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```

when you call `setTitleEnabled(false);`, the title appears in the toolbar