# How to set title of fragment\activity to the toolbar, project template

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-project-template

I created the new project with Navigation Drawer from Project Template, and i want to set the title of toolbar on center like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzvZf.png) from 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlT4r.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your Activity

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText("Home");
```

Comment: Really the support.v7.widget.Toolbar? Use androidx package or the material components library.

Comment: My bad, I took it from a very old project