# How to change font,size of text and set text position center ToolBar Android?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I need to change the font size, the font itself, and center the text in the ToolBar.
I took a template from Bottom Navigation Activity studio.

I was trying setting the text size in themes.xml (I was able to change the background color and text color there)

```
<style name="CustomToolBarStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

I was trying to use this option in themes.xml:

```
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

It didnt help. I tried to follow this instruction:
https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font Throws android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar into an error and get a crash.

[ToolBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2C4H.jpg)

[NavbarTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMQbG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `androidx` don't use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

You have to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

Create `toolbar.xml` in res/layout.
Put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="yourToolBarBackgroundColor"
                >
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="TestToolBar"
                    android:fontFamily="yourFont"
                    android:textSize="yourSizeOfText"
                    android:textColor="yourTextColor" />
    
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
        <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Disable ActionBar in themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.YourProject" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

For night theme you have to do same thing in themes.xml(night)

Then in MainActivity.java in onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

For API level 21+ you can use `app:titleTextAppearance` property of toolbar

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/yourstyle" />
```

and override the default title size in a custom style:

```xml
<style name="yourstyle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">yourFont</item>
</style>
```

For centering, you should follow this answer and if this and none of the other answer works for you from the same post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175403/9917400, than just use a linear layout inside Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set constraint-layout inside the toolbar

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                       android:textColor="@color/blue"
                       android:textSize="16sp"
                       app:fontPath="fonts/xxx" />
             </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```