# AppCompatActivity: detect touches on title?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

In case of an AppCompatActivity with title (set by `setTitle` call), (how) can I detect touches on this title section:

[image]

In case this is not (easily) possible, I'm populating this activity with `setContentView`.

Here is my simplified layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fl"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`fl` will be replaced by `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace` with a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

I wish to detect touches either on the titlebar, or underneath the preference items.

However I tried to call `setOnTouchListener` on `fl` (`FrameLayout fl = findViewById(R.id.fl)`), and it's never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the clicklistener on toolbar since you are using the setTitle for setting the title.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);


if(toolbar != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){

        View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

        if(child instanceof TextView || child instanceof ImageView) {
            child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Show some toast or log message
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: What is `toolbar` exactly?

Comment: It is the blue bar you see on top. It is added to an activity by default.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how can I define it?

Comment: it is already defined, But if you want to customize it you will need to follow few steps. Check this out [Customised toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'toolbar'` on the first line of your example

Comment: Please go through the link I have attached above

Comment: I don't wish to create a layout for the toolbar, just to detect the touches. If it's unavoidable, I'd prefer detecting the touches on the FrameLayout instead. :)

Comment: Edited my answer, Tested this code, it works