# Programmatically add transitionName to Toolbar Title (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to programmatically set the xml property `transitionName` to a `Toolbar` title and then use it for an animation using `ActivityOptionsCompat`?

This is how I declare my `Toolbar`:

```
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle("title");
```

And this is my xml declaration:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

In order to add the animation I have to use the following code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options =
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
    albumCoverImageView,   // The view which starts the transition (Should be myToolbar title)
    transitionName    // The transitionName of the view
    );
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
```

How can I pass the `Toolbar` (`TextView` ?) title to the `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

classes that extend `ViewCompat` are able to call `setTransitionName(String name)`

for example:

```
myToolbar.setTransitionName("ToolbarTransition");
```

**UPDATE** it seems your specifically trying to share the Title so i would do something like the following:

Example xml for MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.divshark.toolbaranimation.MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Activity Title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Activity reference that view:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final AppCompatTextView mTextView = (AppCompatTextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mTextView.setTransitionName("SimpleTransition");
        }

        AppCompatButton mBtnNext = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent secondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, mTextView, mTextView.getTransitionName());
                    startActivity(secondActivity, options.toBundle());
                } else {
                    startActivity(secondActivity);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then in your SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        AppCompatTextView mTextView = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mTextView.setTransitionName("SimpleTransition");
        }
    }
}
```

using this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Activity Title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see you are allowed to call setTransitionName(String name) programmatically using `ViewCompat` views

Good luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Ok thanks! :) but after setting the transition name do I just pass the Toolbar to ActivityOptionsCompat?

Comment: @Signo see my update above, i was able to do this by wrapping a AppCompatTextView  by the Toolbar

Answer (score 9):

You can get the `TextView` instance of the `Toolbar`'s title and set transition by following this code:

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextView mTextViewToolbarTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mTextViewToolbarTitle = getTextViewTitle(mToolbar);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mTextViewTitle.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.your_transition_name));
    }
}
```

Copy this method in your activity:

```
public static TextView getTextViewTitle(Toolbar toolbar){
    TextView textViewTitle = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(view instanceof TextView) {
            textViewTitle = (TextView) view;
            break;
        }
    }
    return textViewTitle;
}
```

then start your new activity with transition by:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    startActivity(intent, 
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, 
                                            mTextViewToolbarTitle, 
                                            getString(R.string.your_transition_name))
                                               .toBundle());
} else {
    startActivity(intent,
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i'm searching for `mTextViewToolbarTitle = getTextViewTitle(mToolbar);`