# How to change ActionBar title font when using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-fonts

I would like to apply custom font to the title of my app which is displayed on the ActionBar. Previously I didn't use any support library and this solution:

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
                "android");
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
yourTextView.setTypeface(face);
```

worked fine for me. But now I am using material design SupportActionBar and this throws NullPointerException. So how to change the ActionBar font when using AppCompat?

Comment: This responce i think can you help   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/2778639

Comment: @user27799 Thanks, this post fixed my problem. If someone has similar problem to mine, just use the method from the linked post, which works fine with the support library v-21.

Comment: Here the solutions, [Actionbar custom design.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966350/changing-the-font-of-the-application-title-in-android/21480484#21480484

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are already successfully using the new toolbar of AppCompat v22+
and that you are importing android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in your activity.

So on your OnCreate you should already have

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

at this point you are almost done:

import java.lang.reflect.field;

and add following lines:

```
TextView yourTextView = null;
try {
    Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    yourTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);
    yourTextView.setTypeface(face);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use Toolbar instead of ActionBar.follow below steps to add toolbar:
1.change your app theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` 
2.Goto project structure from File menu,goto library dependencies,add design library and sync your project.
3.Goto your layout where you want to display ActionBar and write below code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/pccolor"
    android:title="Services"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:elevation="4dp">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

4.In the Activity,write as below:

```
 Toolbar mytoolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar);
```

To customize your title font:

```
fontPath = "Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), fontPath);

TextView tv_ins=(TextView)FindViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
 tv_ins.setText("mytitle");
tv_ins.setTypeface(tf);
```

Try this out Hopes this helps you,if anything wrong please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

prepare Custom Layout ,put text view in action_bar_layout and then call 
**actionbar.setcustomlayout()**