# how to add typeface and select a font from assets folder to customise list activity titles

Tags: android, list, android-activity, typeface

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
/**
 * This class describes an individual sample (the sample title, and the activity class that
 * demonstrates this sample).
 */
  private class Sample {
    private CharSequence title;
    private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

    public Sample(int titleResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        this.activityClass = activityClass;
        this.title = getResources().getString(titleResId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title.toString();
    }
  }

/**
 * The collection of all samples in the app. This gets instantiated in {@link
 * #onCreate(android.os.Bundle)} because the {@link Sample} constructor needs access to {@link
 * android.content.res.Resources}.
 */
 private static Sample[] mSamples;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate the list of samples.
    mSamples = new Sample[]{
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_one, StoryOneActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_two, StoryTwoActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_three, StoryThreeActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_four, StoryFourActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_five, StoryFiveActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_six, StorySixActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_seven, StorySevenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_eight, StoryEightActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_nine, StoryNineActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_ten, StoryTenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_eleven, StoryElevenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twelve, StoryTwelveeActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_thirteen, StoryThirteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_fourteen, StoryFourteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_fifteen, StoryFifteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_sixteen, StorySixteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_seventeen, StorySeventeenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_eighteen, StoryEighteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_nineteen, StoryNineteenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twenty, StoryTwentyActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentyone, StoryTwentyOneActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentytwo, StoryTwentyTwoActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentythree, StoryTwentyThreeActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentyfour, StoryTwentyFourActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentyfive, StoryTwentyFiveActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentysix, StoryTwentySixActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentyseven, StoryTwentySevenActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_story_twentyeight, StoryTwentyEightActivity.class),
    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            mSamples));
 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Launch the sample associated with this list position.
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mSamples[position].activityClass));
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
                    }


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inconvenience with custom fonts is that it should be manually set it to every `TextView`. Please have a look at example below of one approach in your case. Of course font asset should be loaded once in static field to perform better.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            mSamples) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf"));
            return view;
        }
    });
```

Comment: so now can i implement "android:typeface=font.ttf" in listview?

Comment: no you can't add custom fonts in xml, only in code, like in the example `Typeface.createFromAsset(...)`

Comment: @user2857536 try `android.R.id.text1`, in general it should be id of a `TextView`, you'd better know what id is correct.

Comment: okay now no error. but listview is not showing the font. i have even changed the font. but still not showing. this is how my listview is

Comment: <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />

Comment: @user2857536 xml is fine. Do you see just blank space in your list? Doest it work with standard font? Could you update the source code in the topic with actual one.

Comment: ok thanks alot.. it is now working with your given code.. thanks alot.. :)

Comment: and please tell me how to change the direction of text to rtl on the code shown above..

Comment: Since API 17 you can use `TextView.setTextDirection(TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL)`

Comment: another problem.. now listview has custom font.. but title on the actionbar is not the same font.. why?

Comment: Action bar is another story, as you see everywhere you need to set your custom font some coding is required. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)  I think it's time to close this ticket as comments got too long.