# How to change fontsize with custom TypefaceSpan class

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm using the advice from twaddington from this post:

[How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

It's working, but I need to change the font size.  How do I do this?  I tried modifying the argument int maxSize from

```
private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);
```

Is is done from the TypefaceSpan class or in onCreate method?

TypefaceSpan

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
/** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

private Typeface mTypeface;

/**
* Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link Spannable}.
*/
public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

if (mTypeface == null) {
mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
.getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

// Cache the loaded Typeface
sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
}
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
// Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
// Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}
}
```

MainActivity onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("TEST TITLE");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MotorwerkOblique.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add it in paint, everytime you are updating you are applying a new Paint which should specify the textSize. Think of a typeface more of a font/set of characters. The Android documentation states:

> The Typeface class specifies the typeface and intrinsic style of a
>   font. This is used in the paint, along with optionally Paint settings
>   like textSize, textSkewX, textScaleX to specify how text appears when
>   drawn (and measured).

After reading this, I would suggest the following to be done. (Not sure if this would do what you want. But let me know)

```
@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
    p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
    p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    p.setTextSize(25);//or what ever size you want
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
    tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
    tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    tp.setTextSize(25);//or what ever size you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do the text rendering yourself and just want to focus on using the utility there are three Span types recognized by the text renderer that will achieve this.

[`RelativeSizeSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html)
This span will take an absolute value to be multiplied to the current size of the text range. This is mostly used for emphasis. So a positive value will increase the size by the factor and a negative will decrease the size by a factor.

[`TextAppearanceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html)
This span allows you to dereference a named style so that you can do something like, for this text range use, `R.style.TextAppearance.ExtraAwesomseText`. Where that style has something like:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.ExtraAwesomeText">
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

**OR**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.ExtraAwesomeText">
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#005500</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

It's up to you how specific you want to be. But this Span lets you update the text range without having to know all the details of the current text Range since it sets absolutes. It also is a little cleaner since you don't have to mess with too code in the chance you want to update a type of text across your entire app. Such spans will just automatically be applied after the style change.

[`RasterizerSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RasterizerSpan.html)

This one is like the do whatever you want to update the appearance span. It just gives you the TextPaint being used for the text range and you can just change it for the rest of the span. So you can do things like make it italic, bold, add text shadow etc. It's pretty cool. This combined with some methods from Activity can really allow you to define some markup extensions to your app depending on how complex a design you have. But a lot of times you can just use it for inline changes like:

```
charSequence.setSpan(new RasterizerSpan() {

     public void updateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint) {
            // add a text shadow to the given range
            textPaint.setShadowLayer(5, 5, 5 0x005500);
     }
 }, 0, charSequence.length() - 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I usually hold out on using the `RasterizerSpan` because it's pretty much brute force and for things like defining custom  templates or just really bizarre one-offs.