# How to make custom font in actionbar show up immediately

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

In order to change the font which is inside my actionbar, I implemented a custom TypefaceSpan class and used a SpannableString in my onCreate.

This has what I did:
[How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title/15181195#15181195)

In the comments user, artwork ,said,

> In the moment of starting the app, the default title style is visible
>   and about 1 sec later the custom style appears.

Then the guy who answered the question said

> "that's because your activity's theme is being applied to the
>   DecorView before your code has spun up. You can work around this by
>   hiding the action bar in your theme, then show it as your activity is
>   being created."

I am not sure how to implement the following. Nor am I sure that is able to be done in my customized action bar.

And this is how I styled my actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Customaction" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customaction</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customaction</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Customaction</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Customaction</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Customaction</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_customaction</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_customaction</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Customaction</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_customaction</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_customaction</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_customaction</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_customaction</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_customaction</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customaction</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Customaction" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_customaction</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Customaction.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customaction</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customaction</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is part of what I have in my MainActivity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Make sure you find out why it appears after a whole 1 second after the app appears
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("GetDisciplined");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "roboto-lightitalic.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.merge);
```

I am just trying to solve the problem of the Custom ActionBar Font showing up after one second by making it show up immediately, but I am unsure to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it (not a very nice way) is to use a custom layout for your titlebar where you use a custom textview that displays the title.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
private static Typeface customFont = null;

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }

    if (customFont == null) {
        customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/custom_font.ttf");
    }
    setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

}

In your activity:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
 setContentView(R.layout.activities);
 getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
```

And the title in the layout uses that CustomTextView to hold the title.

Once again, pretty messy solution, but will do what you want it to.

Comment: Create a layout for the title bar