# Android: How to give custom font style to action bar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do we customize the font style of title of action bar. The font's style is also customized and has to be imported into the application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

Comment: BTW, I found that duplicate typing "custom font actionbar" in Google. I'm still wondering how come you didn't ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Hope it helps

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8)

**UPD:** The source code of custom TypefaceSpan is [here](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8)