# How to add buttons like refresh and search in ToolBar in Android?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

[image]

I have made a ToolBar, but when I add menu items in menu.xml it always shows as an overflow.
How do I add it separately?
Moreover the Title is shown in the middle (vertically), how do I show it at the top?

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity" >

       <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:orderInCategory="1" 
          android:menuCategory="secondary"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.toolbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //toolbar.setTitle("Title");
       // toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity" >

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
         app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Related post - [How to set menu to Toolbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35648913/465053)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

OK, I got the icons because I wrote in menu.xml `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` instead of `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` since i am using v7 library.

However the title is coming at center of extended toolbar. How to make it appear at the top?

Comment: try to use android:gravity="top" in your Toolbar.

Comment: You made my day with "app:" instead of "android:". It's really not clear from the first sight.

Comment: i also replace app instead of android

Answer (score 5):

Try to do this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and if you made your custom toolbar (which i presume you did) then you can use the simplest way possible to do this:

```
toolbarTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
toolbarSubTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_subtitle);
toolbarTitle.setText("Title");
toolbarSubTitle.setText("Subtitle");
```

Same goes for any other views you put in your toolbar. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line at the top:

`"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

and then use:

`app:showasaction="ifroom"`

Answer (score 0):

To control the location of the title you may want to set a custom font as explained here (by twaddington): [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

Then to relocate the position of the text, in `updateMeasureState()` you would add `p.baselineShift += (int) (p.ascent() * R);`
Similarly in `updateDrawState()` add `tp.baselineShift += (int) (tp.ascent() * R);`
Where R is double between -1 and 1.

Comment: This is complex.Is there any attribute to set it.