# Default ActionBar with Settings button

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-actionbar

Although I am new in android developing, lately, I have been trying to add a settings button in the default ActionBar that Android Studio provides (as shown in the picture below). However, all the tutorials I have stamped on start with changing the app Theme to: `android:theme="@style/Theme.APpCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Is there any way I can avoid changing Theme and just add that setting about in the default ActionBar?

[image: ActionBar that Android documentation suggests]

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648913/how-to-set-menu-to-toolbar-in-android

Comment: Totally helped. I guess this way it will let me keep the default ActionBar of Android Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by inflating your menu to the toolbar.
Override this method in your java class.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_custom_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

You custom menu should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/night_mode"
    android:title="?attr/theme_text"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="?attr/theme_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/about_text"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="?attr/about_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="@string/action_logout_text"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="?attr/logout_icon"/>
```

Here's something more about menus: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus