# Navigation Component with different Toolbars&Menus

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on app that uses Navigation pattern.
Now I have an Activity and few fragments. 
Each Fragment has a unique functionality so I created a separate toolbar for each fragment: collapsing, usual or no toolbar at all.
I used the following example: https://android.jlelse.eu/instagram-style-navigation-using-navigation-component-854037cf1389

It works pretty well, but now I am taking an issue if I want to set some menu items in the toolbar.

For example, I would like to add a settings menu to the toolbar of the Profile Fragment

I tried setting a menu item, but it simply never appears and I think the method doesn't get called at all..

Is it possible to solve this issue without changing the whole architecture logic?

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, container, false)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }
```

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.toolbar.apply {
            setupWithNavController(findNavController())
        }
    }
```

```
  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.action_get_info)
            Toast.makeText(context!!, "test message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_get_info"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:title="Settings"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context="com.example.MyFragment">


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout 
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              style="@style/ToolbarAppearance"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

              <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_test_image" />
        </RelativeLayout>    

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting setSupportActionBar(toolbar)?

Comment: Thanks  @peshkira, but since it's a fragment I cannot use "setSupportActionBar".
I have one Activity and all the rest are Fragments

Comment: you can, if you access the activity in onActivityCreated for example.

Comment: @peshkira Please can you show some example, maybe?:)

Comment: @peshkira, Thank you for your help.
I solved the issue for now using this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648913/how-to-set-menu-to-toolbar-in-android